# 'Add' up the letters in a word

Tags: code-golf, word

My dad is a retired teacher, and he used to give combined spelling and math quizzes, where the student would spell a word, and then 'score' the word by adding up the letters, where a=1, b=2, etc. (e.g. cat = 3+1+20=24).  This made grading the quizzes easier, as he would just have to check for incorrect 'scores' rather than incorrectly spelled words, and had the added benefit of testing 2 skills at once.

He hired a friend of mine to write a program that would score words for him, so he could generate lengthy answer keys without error.  This problem is inspired by that program.

Requirements:

1. Accept any word with uppercase and lowercase letters
2. Return an error for any special characters, i.e. spaces, hyphens, @^%# etc.
3. a=1, b=2,... and A=1, B=2,...
4. Print the score of the word
5. (Optional) check that the word is in a dictionary after scoring, and print a warning if it is not.
6. No importing an external letter->number dictionary.  You must generate it yourself.

Any language is acceptable. This is similar to the '[digital root battle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/my-word-can-beat-up-your-word),' but much simpler.

Comment: Can a word contain numbers? Shall I throw an Exception or something similar if it contains numbers?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a code golf?

Comment: @Helper Method: A word containing a number should throw an exception or something similar

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Yes, how should I explicitly mark it as such?

Comment: @Zach Using the `code-golf` tag.

Comment: The warning message should be given in some way.

Comment: @Helper Method: what would you suggest?

Comment: Did your dad even bother teaching the "I before E except after C" rule?

Comment: Yeah, only checking scores? I'd spell cat as `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`. Dad: Score is 24? That's right!

Comment: @ericw31415 Every hashing function has collisions ;-).  So far none of his students have tried that attack vector

Comment: @Zach Also, it would be too complex if his dad made his students do SHA-512 of their words.

Comment: @ericw31415 yes, but to do that you need to know how to spell cat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Golfscript - 23 chars

```
0\{.31&.(.26%=@64///+}/
```

Ensure there are no trailing newlines in input (e.g. use `echo -n`).

Comment: We have a new winner!

Comment: Generally, external filtering [is supposed to be included in character count somehow](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions/274#274) (Ctrl-f external filtering.), though I assume it's only 2 extra characters to do without.

Comment: @Jesse: `echo -n` really doesn't count as external filtering -- in fact the answer you linked suggests it as a valid form for input.

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby, 43 characters

```
$_=gets.upcase;p~/[^A-Z]/?_: $_.sum-64*~/$/
```

The error message this generates isn't exactly helpful, though.
Both solutions posted here assume the input has no trailing linebreak, so to test them, use `echo -n`.

### Ruby, 76 characters with dictionary check

```
l=STDIN.gets;$_=l.upcase;p~/[^A-Z]/?_: $_.sum-64*~/$/;[*$<].index(l)||$><<?W
```

The warning message consists of the single character "W". The path to the dictionary has to be supplied via ARGV. Example usage:

```
$ echo -n asd | ruby addletters.rb /usr/share/dict/words
24
W
$ echo -n cat | ruby addletters.rb /usr/share/dict/words
24
```

Comment: You could chop of 9 characters in the dictionary check version by making the error message an exclamation mark.

Comment: You get a consolation prize for the shortest entry with a dictionary check.  Way to go!

Comment: Why was the dictionary check proposed if it doesn't give you any real edge (on the contrary, it just bloated the code)?

Answer (score 8):

## Python (<strike>65</strike> 64)

```
print sum(['',ord(i)-64]['@'<i<'[']for i in raw_input().upper())
```

This raises an error if the word contains non-letter characters, but not a helpful or informative one.  (Edit: tip of the hat to st0le for the indexing trick.)

Comment: `print sum(['',ord(i)-64]['@'<i<'[']for i in raw_input().upper())` shaved a couple of chars.

Comment: Just one char actually. :-\

Comment: Save 4 characters by using `input`; forces user to put quotes around input strings, but "user-friendly" and "not dangerous" aren't in the spec!

Comment: Well, just change it to Python 3! `raw_input`→`input`

Comment: `print sum([i,ord(i)-64]['@'<i<'[']for i in raw_input().upper())`

another byte shaved

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2.6 (72 Chars) Without dictionary check

```
print sum(map(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".index, raw_input().lower()))
```

## Python 2.6 (178 Chars*) With dictionary check

```
w=raw_input().lower()
print sum(map(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".index, w))
if w not in open('/usr/share/dict/american-english').read().split():
 print('Word not in dictionary')
```

<sub>*Can be lowered to 156 with a less helpful error message. :-)</sub>

Thanks to all commenters for helping improve this.

Comment: You might want to consider using the `sum` builtin with a generator expression, rather than a `for` loop.  It would let you trim off a few chars (~17).

Comment: @jloy: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the parentheses on print can be eliminated

Comment: its seems you're using `a` just once, so use the literal itself...`"0abc....z".index(i)` will work equivalently.

Comment: The `0` in your scoring array is clever, but it also means that `cat0` is accepted without error, which isn't right, I think.  Which is too bad, since it would allow you to pass `map(a.index,w)` to `sum` instead (substituting the literal for `a` as st0le suggests).

Comment: @jloy: The dictionary check version says that `cat0` is not the dictionary.  Am I supposed to do more error checking then that?

Comment: The dictionary check version is good, the shorter version needs to throw some sort of error, though it looks like that's only spelled out in the comments to the original question.

Comment: @jloy: Hmm, you're right.  I think I have fixed that now.

Answer (score 4):

## Java + Google Guava libraries, 347 characters, with dictionary check

**Unreadable 1 long string version :-)**

```
import java.io.*;import com.google.common.base.*;import com.google.common.io.*;class C{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int s=0;for(int c:a[0].toUpperCase().toCharArray()){assert(c>64&&c<91);s+=c-64;}String d=Files.toString(new File(a[1]),Charsets.UTF_8);if(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(d,a[0]))System.out.println("w");System.out.println(s);}}
```

**Human-readable version (sort of :-))**

```
import java.io.*;

import com.google.common.base.*;
import com.google.common.io.*;

class C {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        int s=0;

        for(int c : a[0].toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(c);
            assert(c > 64 && c < 91);
            s += c - 64;
        }

        String d = Files.toString(new File(a[1]), Charsets.UTF_8);

        if (d.contains(a[0])) System.out.println("w");

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The dictionary path is now passed in via `a[1]`, for assertions to work you have to use the `-ea`flag (+3 more chars). As for the dictionary, the dict `/usr/share/dict/words` (should be available on most *nix systems) has been used.

Comment: So far you're the only one with a dictionary check, so +1

Comment: one line? this isn't particularily readable this way, though i guess it saves chars

Comment: I will add a more readable solution (and also a shorter one using Google Guava to reduce boilerplate code).

Comment: You just allow ascii, but use Charset.UTF-8?

Comment: Because the String `UTF-8` is shorter than the other charsets :-).

Answer (score 4):

### Scala: 59 chars, 7 of them payload, no dict:

```
(0/:"Payload".map(c=>if(c.isLetter)(c-'A')%32 else-999))(_+_)
67
```

No dictionary so far. Negative result means: Negative!

```
(0/:"Pay!wall?".map(c=>if(c.isLetter)(c-'A')%32 else-999))(_+_)   
-1915
```

Handles German Umlaute gracefully, by the way:

```
(0/:"Müllrößchen".map(c=>if(c.isLetter)(c-'A')%32 else-999))(_+_)
155
```

Comment: Wow, less chars than the Perl version (and still more readable).

Comment: I tried SHiNKiROUs and chinesis-Perl-solution, but they didn't work for me. Saved them as `alpha.pl` and started them by `perl alpha.pl`. Do they just handle Ascii? Well - at Perl is such an old beast ... :)

Comment: Perl and Unicode is a big mess. You probably have to run them as `perl -M5.010 alpha.pl` or something like that.

Comment: I heard that I need single quotes instead of double quotes on Linux, and this worked, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Python (80)

```
w=raw_input().lower()
s=0
for l in w:s+=range(97,123).index(ord(l))+1
print s
```

### Python v2 (65 but char ` will get accepted)

```
print sum(map(range(96,123).index,map(ord,raw_input().lower())))
```

### v3 (60 chars, @ will be accepted but not counted, thanks jloy)

```
print sum(map(range(64,91).index,map(ord,input().upper())))
```

Comment: HINT: THERE IS A WAY TO REMOVE ONE MORE CHAR FROM YOUR SOLUTIONS. :)

Comment: @jloy What a helpful 'hint'. ;)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 95 chars with dictionary

```
d=input().lower()
print(d in open("d").read()and sum(['',ord(c)-96]['`'<c<'{']for c in d)or'f')
```

The dictionary has to be in a file called d.

#### Python 3, 61 without dictionary, but stolen idea

```
print(sum(['',ord(c)-96]['`'<c<'{']for c in input().lower()))
```

Answer (score 3):

## VB.NET, <s>84</s> <s>82</s> <s>73</s> 71

```
Console.Write(Console.ReadLine.Sum(Function(c)Asc(Char.ToUpper(c))-64))
```

**Edit:** With validation is:

```
Dim r=Console.ReadLine
Console.Write(If(r.All(AddressOf Char.IsLetter),r.Sum(Function(c)Asc(Char.ToUpper(c))-64),"Invalid input."))
```

129 characters. In which case:

## C#, 118

```
var r=Console.ReadLine();Console.Write(r.All(char.IsLetter)?r.Sum(c=>char.ToUpper(c)-64).ToString():"Invalid input.");
```

Comment: This doesn't validate the input.

Comment: Oops! Hold on a second...

Comment: I think you should provide complete programs. Your C# solution doesn’t compile; you need to place it in a Main method inside a class declaration, and count all the characters.

Comment: No, because that code doesn't do anything, and it's not fair to disadvantage users of object-oriented languages. This is valid C#/VB.NET anyways.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl <strike>(52)</strike> (48)

golfed even more thanks to [Timwi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi)

`perl -lpe "($w=uc)=~/[^A-Z]/&&die;$w=~s/./$_-=64-ord$&/ge"`

Comment: You're missing the `-e` flag there.

Comment: You should at least include the `p` and `l` interpreter flags in your character count. See [this discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions) on meta.

Comment: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "(="
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you're running on unix, change double quotes to single ones

Comment: @Timwi: 'Accept any word with uppercase and lowercase letters' went to the wrong thread, sorry. I deleted it now. @chinese: Yes, thanks, with single quotes it's ok. As long as I restrict myself to ascii input. :)

Comment: You get a consolation prize for the shortest non-golfscript entry.

Answer (score 3):

## Improving slightly on John's answer: Python (90)

```
s=0
for i in raw_input().lower():
 s+=("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".index(i)+1)
print(s)
```

Comment: adding the dummy char in the string beginning is shorter...parentheses can be removed

Answer (score 3):

## **Erlang, 104**

```
a()->
a(string:to_lower(io:get_line([])),0).
a([_|[]],S)->
S;
a([C|R],S) when C<${, C>=$`->
a(R,S+C-$`).
```

Answer (score 3):

**Golfscript - 39 chars**

```
n%~{.96>{96}{64}if-..26>\0<|{0/}*}%{+}*
```

The error it throws is not exactly the best, but hey, it aborts execution.

Comment: I don't know anything about golfscript, so I'm going to assume this meets the requirements and declare you the winner!

Comment: Whoops, you've been beat!  I guess 2 days isn't long enough to wait on a code golf question?

Answer (score 3):

### PYTHON <s>62</s> 68* Characters

```
print sum(map(chr,range(65,91)).index(c)+1 for c in input().upper())
```

Requires user to input strings using quotes, and is not safe (`input` executes code), but, as I said in a comment to another post, "user-friendly" and "not a security risk" ain't in the spec!

---

<sub>* I forgot about `print`, dammit.</sub>

Comment: [jloy's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/add-up-the-letters-in-a-word/2191#2191) is still shorter, actually, because of the `input`/`raw_input` difference.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 17 bytes

```
?osṁo%32c¹¨eŻ→¨Λ√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b99fvHDnY35qsZGyYd2HlqRenT3o7ZJh1acm/2oY9b///@jlZITS5R0lJwdQ4CkoZExkFRW1FKKBQA)

Returns 'error' for invalid input, score of word otherwise.

```
?              Λ√       # if every element is a letter
 os                     # return the string of
   ṁ    c¹              # the sum of all their ASCII values
    o%32                # MOD 32
          ¨eŻ→¨         # otherwise, return the compressed string
                        # "error"
```

---

If it's acceptable to return '0' as the 'error' for invalid input, we can have a <s>11 byte</s> <s>10 byte</s> [9 byte](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@h5WoPdzaqGhudW5D7qGPW////o5WSE0uUdJScHUOAZKKhkTGQUlbUUooFAA) solution:

```
§&ṁ%32Πm√
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
lvAyk>})D0åi0ëO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/p8yxMtuuVtPF4PDSTIPDq/3//09OLAEA) Returns `0` on error.

```
lvAyk>})D0åi0ëO  # full program
 v               # for y in...
                 # implicit input...
l                # lowercased...
    k            # push 0-based index of...
   y             # y...
    k            # in...
  A              # the lowercase alphabet...
    k            # or -1 if not found...
     >           # plus 1
      }          # end loop
           i     # if...
         0       # 0...
          å      # is in...
       )         # stack...
            0    # push 0
             ë   # else...
              O  # push sum...
        D        # of stack
                 # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9, 69

```
w=gets.chop.upcase
w[/[^A-Z]/]&&fail
p w.bytes.inject(0){|s,b|s+b-64}
```

Comment: Does only handle ascii characters. I thought Ruby is from our century? :)

Comment: @user unknown: The spec doesn't say it has to. Doing it would be rather complicated...

Answer (score 2):

### Perl (71)

```
($a)=lc<>;$a=~/[^a-z]/i&&die;$x+=ord$_ for split//,$a;die$x-96*length$a;
```

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 50(53)

Gives an error on bad characters, but not a very good one (50 characters):

```
);[{""123,97>+91,65>+?}/].-1?0<{{26%1+}%{+}*}{@}if
```

Gives "E" on error instead (53 characters):

```
);[{""123,97>+91,65>+?}/].-1?0<{{26%1+}%{+}*}{;"E"}if
```

The alphabet-generating snippet `123,97>+` is stolen from Ventero .

Answer (score 2):

## J (55)

```
+/64-~-&32`]@.(<&97)`_:@.(<&65)`_:@.(>&122)"0,I.a.&e."0
```

This satisfies all the conditions except the dictionary one. As an error condition, it returns "infinity" (the underscore symbol in J) for words that contain anything but letters.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell (127)

(raises an error on weird characters) 
(also: the space between `toUpper.` and `\x` is needed otherwise it parses it as`(toUpper)` `.\` `(x)`)

```
import Char
main=getLine>>=putStrLn.show.sum.(map$(-65+).ord.toUpper. \x->if x`elem`['A'..'Z']++['a'..'z']then x else error"")
```

## Haskell (70)

(does not raise an error, but 45% shorter)

```
import Char
main=getLine>>=putStrLn.show.sum.(map$(-65+).ord.toUpper)
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++ (<s>111</s> 107)

```
void main(){int a=0;s8*b=new s8[99];for(cin>>b;*b;)if(isalpha(*b))a+=tolower(*b++)-96;else return;cout<<a;}
```

---

The "set up"/etc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    typedef __int8 s8;
#else
    typedef signed char s8;
#endif
```

---

["Undefined" behavior](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21/761) (It's more 'bad practice' than 'undefined', but oh well):

- `void main()` That says it all.
- I'm using `new` without `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ŒuØAiⱮoµS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNLDMxwzH21cl39oa/D///@VnBNLlAA)

Seemingly, it turns out a byte shorter to actually error than to return 0.

```
Œu           Uppercase the input,
    i        find the index (or 0 if not found)
     Ɱ       of each letter from the input
  ØA         in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
      o      replace any 0 with the corresponding character of the input,
       µS    then take the sum.
```

Jelly errors if it attempts to add integers and strings together, and although two strings can be added together by `+`, this still errors in the case of a fully symbolic input because `S` is defined specifically as a reduce starting from zero.

Comment: Nice.  It'll be tough to better (or even match) 9-bytes...

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript 1.8, 80 chars

Surprisingly readable!

```
alert(Array.reduce(prompt().toLowerCase(),function(a,b)a+b.charCodeAt(0)-96,0))
```

Comment: For use in Chrome I had to convert it a little: `alert(prompt().toLowerCase().split("").reduce(function(a,b){return a+b.charCodeAt(0)-96},0))`. I still like JavaScript solutions most :)

Comment: It doesn't return an error when you do invalid character???

Answer (score 1):

### APL (34)

```
+/{⍵∊⍳26:⍵}¨{64-⍨A-32×96<A←⎕UCS⍵}⍞
```

Gives either the score, or a `VALUE ERROR` if there are non-alphabetic characters in the input.

Explanation:

- `⍞`: read a line of input
- `{`...`}`: function applied to every character of input
- `A←⎕UCS⍵`: store the ASCII value of the current character in `A`
- `A-32×96<A`: make character uppercase: from `A` is subtracted 32 if `96<A` (so, if it's uppercase), otherwise 0
- `64-⍨`: subtract 64 from this, giving A=1, B=2 ...
- `¨`: apply this function to every character:
- `⍵∊⍳26`: if the character is between 1 and 26...
- `:⍵`: then return ⍵ (and since there's no else clause there will be a `VALUE ERROR` if it's not between 1 and 26)
- `+/`: sum all the values together (and this value is automatically outputted because it's the final result).

Answer (score 1):

## F# (no validation) <strike>79</strike> 57 chars

```
let a w=w|>Seq.fold(fun a b->a+(int b)-65)0|>printfn"%i"
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 98 bytes

```
 int a(char *s){int b=0;while(*s){if(!isalpha(*s))throw 1;b+=(toupper(*(s++))-64);}printf("%d",b);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# with validation: 108 chars (with 12 for error message):

```cs
var s=Console.ReadLine();Console.Write(s.All(Char.IsLetter)?s.Sum(x=>x&'_'-'@').ToString():"Invalid input");
```

## C# without validation: <strike>60</strike> 53 chars:

```cs
Console.Write(Console.ReadLine().Sum(x=>x&'_'-'@'));
```

Comment: In the second one without validation, you can reduce the characters even more by removing the s variable declaration and using Console.ReadLine() inline.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 60 bytes

```
s=>[...s.toUpperCase()].reduce((a,b)=>a+b.charCodeAt()-64,0)
```

If the program **must** return an error on invalid inputs, then 80 bytes:

```
s=>/[^a-z]/i.test(s)?_:[...s.toUpperCase()].reduce((a,b)=>a+b.charCodeAt()-64,0)
```

If an input is invalid, then the console will say that `_` is not defined (there must not already be a variable defined called `_`).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 68 Bytes

This can almost certainly be golfed more

```js
w=>[...w.toLowerCase()].map(v=>v.charCodeAt()-96).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
```

### With dictionary check (Node.js & Unix Descendants only) 195 Bytes

Uses `/usr/share/dict/words`, and can definitely be shortened (see the warn message)

```js
w=>(require("fs").readFile("/usr/share/dict/words",(e,t)=>!(t+"").split`
`.includes(w=w.toLowerCase())&&console.warn(w+" not found in dict")),[...w].map(v=>v.charCodeAt()-96).reduce((a,b)=>a+b))
```

Comment: For an error message, you do `console.error()`, not `console.warn()`.

Comment: But the challenge said to warn (5. (Optional) check that the word is in a dictionary after scoring, and print a **warning** if it is not.) Don't mean to be pedantic, but the challenge specified a warning

Comment: @SpeedyNinja I think it still counts, that isn't really the point of the challenge...

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ it is 1 character shorter ;)

Comment: @SpeedyNinja You're right, I misread.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>58</s> 55

```
print(sum(ord(x)%32for x in input()if x.isalpha()or z))
```

without dictionary or stolen idea but still unhelpful error ;)

thx @Eᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏ

Test [here](https://repl.it/CO5q/1).

Comment: I think you can save a byte by switching to python 2 and doing `print<SPACE>sum(ord(.......`, removing the 2 parentheses around the expression.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ that is right but than the input has to be in parenthesis and I don't want to promote python 2 ;)

Comment: PYTHON 2 IS LIFE!! and also, I don't think that would require the input to be parenthesized?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ sry i meant quoted.
`input()` in python3 is `raw_input()` in python2

Comment: oh, I forgot. Hm.

Answer (score 1):

### [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev), 51 bytes

```js
w=>w.split``.reduce((a,l)=>a+parseInt(l,36)-9,0)||x
```

Surprised nobody's made this golf yet.

Explanation:

```js
w =>                // Function with w as argument
w.split``           // Split w into an array of characters
.reduce((a,l)=>a+   // Take the sum of...
parseInt(l,36)-9    // The value of the letter in base 36, then subtract nine (gives the number of the letter)
,0)||x              // Error if it's NaN (there was a special character), because x is not defined
```

Comment: Does this error for input of "123"?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen No, but my understanding of the requirements was that only symbols/special characters had to be handled, not numbers. If numbers also need to be handled it would be 12 more bytes. (As far as I can tell, none of the other JS answers error if given symbols anyway)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 26 bytes

```perl
/\PL/||map$\+=037&ord,@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18/JsBHv6YmN7FAJUbb1sDYXC2/KEXHwa22@v9/RyD4l19QkpmfV/xft8ANAA)

Outputs nothing as its error condition

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 48 bytes

`0 -rot bounds [do] [i] c@ 32 xor 64 - + [loop] .`

(takes arguments from the stack)

a version that reads from stdin:

`0 pad pad pad stdin read-line 2drop bounds [do] [i] c@ 32 xor [if] 64  - + [loop] .`

the second version, but commented:

```
0 pad \ used later
pad \ where to put the bytes
pad \ how many bytes (it's an address, so it's a big number, and forth doesn't have types)
stdin \ where to get the bytes
read-line \ get the bytes (also returns the number of bytes got)
2drop \ ignore IO errors 
bounds \ turn an address and a length into a start and end address
[do] \ iterate over all the address in said range 
[i] \ get the current address
c@ \ get the character at the current address
32 xor \ make it uppercase
64 - \ letter to number (eg a -> 1)
+ \ add number to total (this is what the 0 is for)
[loop] \ end loop
. \ print resulting number
```

Comment: This doesn't handle uppercase characters in the input correctly, but the fix actually saves a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf@LlRScE0uU/hso6Bbllygk5ZfmpRQrRKfkxypEZ8YqJDsoGBsp5BcpWJop6CpoK0Tn5OcXxCro/f8PAA)

That being said, this also doesn't appear to perform the required input validation. If validation is too clunky, feel free to keep a non-validating version as well, so long as you mark it as such.

Also I'm not entirely sure that that snippet is a valid submission, but you save two more bytes by making it a named function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ʀA[⁰øA∑|u
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiyoBBW+KBsMO4QeKIkXx1IiwiIiwiaGl1NyJd)
Ties with jelly but pushes -1 if there is an error.

```
ʀA             # check if every character is in the alphabet
  [⁰øA∑        # if true, sum the character values of the input string
        |u     # else, return -1
```

Comment: You don't need the `⁰`, implicit input will work.

Comment: also, you can get 7 bytes returning 0: `øA∑?ʀA∧`

Comment: i dont think returning 0 is okay here because an empty word scores 0

Answer (score 0):

## C, 97 Chars

```c
int r(c*z){int x=0;while(*z){char w=tolower(*(z++));if(w<96|w>122)return-1;x+=w-96;}return x;}
```

It returns -1 if there's an invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

## K, 44

```
{$[=/x in\:a:.Q.a,.Q.A;+/(a!,/2#,1+!26)x;`]}
```

Returns ` for any non alphabetic input

Answer (score 0):

### VBA 120

```vb
Sub s(t)
For i=1 To Len(t)
a=Asc(Mid(t,i,1))-64
a=IIf(a>32,a-32,a)
If a<1 Or a>26 Then Print
b=b+a
Next
MsgBox b
End Sub
```

`Print` does not cause a compile-time error, though the syntax is invalid, which causes an exception to be thrown and the program to exit if, and only if, the character is not an upper- or lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl (<del>42</del> 31)

```perl
perl -F -pale '$c+=ord(uc$_)-64for@F;$_=$c'
```

I hope counting F, p, a and l as 1 character was correct.