# Print the digital root

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

<sup>This is different from [My Word can beat up your Word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/my-word-can-beat-up-your-word) as it is less complex and only requires you to calculate it, and not compare them.</sup>

To find the digital root, take all of the digits of a number, add them, and repeat until you get a one-digit number. For example, if the number was `12345`, you would add `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`, getting `15`. You would then add `1` and `5`, giving you `6`.

#### Your task

Given an integer ***N*** (0 <= ***N*** <= 10000) through **STDIN**, print the digital root of ***N***.

#### Test cases

```
1 -> 1
45 -> 9
341 -> 8
6801 -> 6
59613 -> 6
495106 -> 7
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Can we take the input as a string?

Comment: @Dopapp Yes....

Comment: This is called a [digital root](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root).

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/equality-in-the-sum-of-digits)

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/count-sum-of-all-digits)

Comment: Maybe a subtask of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90916/34531).

Comment: *Very* closely related to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1128/42963) ... maybe close enough for a dupe.

Comment: @nimi That's why I had the feeling I had done something like this before..

Comment: Please be more precise when saying `number`. In particular. must input `0` be supported?

Comment: @TimmyD I think that this one is the much cleaner challenge without adding letter to integer conversion, computing the function for two values and including the literal `STALEMATE`. It might be better to close the other one as a dupe of this.

Comment: @MartinEnder Perhaps. Points out another reason why using the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is encouraged.

Comment: @MartinEnder I retracted my close vote, I think it's unfair to close a good challenge as a dupe of another more complex challenge.

Comment: You should add 10 as a test case. My algorithm was working fine for all your test cases, but was wrong for 10!

Answer (score 28):

### Pyke, 1 byte

```
s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=s&input=495106)

Takes the digital root of the input

Answer (score 22):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7 5 4</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḃ9Ṫ
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biDOeG5qg&input=&args=NTk2MTM)** or [all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biDOeG5qgrFvMOH4oKsRw&input=&args=WzEsMTgsNDUsMzQxLDY4MDEsNTk2MTMsNDk1MTA2XQ)

#### How?

The [digital root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitalRoot.html) is known to obey the formula (n-1)%9+1.
This is the same as the last digit in bijective base 9
(and due to implementation that `0ḃ9=[]` and `[]Ṫ=0` this handles the edge-case of zero).

```
ḃ9Ṫ - Main link: n
ḃ9  - convert to bijective base 9 digits (a list)
  Ṫ - tail (get the last digit)
```

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>16</s> 10 bytes

```
n=>--n%9+1
```

Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>--n%9+1

console.log(f(1)); // -> 1
console.log(f(45)); // -> 9
console.log(f(341)); // -> 8
console.log(f(6801)); // -> 6
console.log(f(59613)); // -> 6
console.log(f(495106)); // -> 7
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python, <s>16</s> 20 bytes

+4 bytes to handle edge case of zero.

```python
lambda n:n and~-n%9+1
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EHnu/2)**

Comment: Wow. This is so easy it can be ported to any language. You can even `~-input()%9+1`

Comment: Doesn't work for 0 unfortunately.

Comment: @KarlNapf Wouldn't that need a `print`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, possibly. I just tested it in the REPL environment and that did it.

Comment: @Emigna indeed it does not, it works for the natural numbers. We all know `0` is not a number. My Jelly solution works for 0. Negative numbers "work" with both - Jelly keeping the (one) sign, this dumping it.

Comment: I know the Jelly version works (as it uses the bijective base). I've always counted 0 as a number though. Hopefully the OP can confirm if we need to support it (as I can change back to my shorter code if we can ignore 0)

Comment: @JonathanAllan 0 is a number. It is no natural number though. The OP should clarify this.

Comment: @KarlNapf Who said numbers are going to be natural? `0 <= N <= 10000`, and *N* is just used as a variable meaning *number*. I would argue that it would be good to use *n* instead of *N*, though.

Comment: @ the anonymous user who attempted an edit - it would have actually broken the code (made an input of `0` result in `9` rather than `0`, which is what is catered for by the `n and` part of the code) furthermore it would have counted as 19 bytes not 13 (since the `print` and the space must be counted).

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
9X\
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OVhc&input=WzEgNDUgMzQxIDY4MDEgNTk2MTMgNDk1MTA2XQ)

A lot of (now deleted answers) tried using modulo 9 to get the result. This is a great shortcut, but unfortunately does not work for multiples of 9. MATL has a function for modulo on the interval `[1, n]`. Using this modulo, we have `1 % 3 == 1, 2 % 3 == 2, 3 % 3 == 3, 4 % 3 == 1`, etc. This answer simply takes the input modulo nine using this custom modulo.

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, <s>27</s> 11 bytes

```
Mod[#,9,1]&
```

Mathematica's `Mod` takes a third parameter as an offset of the resulting range of the modulo. This avoids decrementing the input and incrementing the output.

Answer (score 7):

### Julia, 12 bytes

```
!n=mod1(n,9)
```

or

```
n->mod1(n,9)
```

`mod1` is an alternative to `mod` which maps to the range `[1, n]` instead of `[0, n)`.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 15 Bytes

```php
<?=--$argn%9+1;
```

Previous version PHP, 55 Bytes

```
$n=$argn;while($n>9)$n=array_sum(Str_split($n));echo$n;
```

Comment: Exactly how I did it!

Comment: @CT14.IT I can delete this post if you wish. Your deleted post ws 1 minute earlier and you have only forgot the while loop

Comment: Nah the deleted answer was wrong because I didn't read the question properly to start with, I didnt attempt to sum the generated number

Comment: You can add the trick of other answers `<?=--$argv[1]%9+1?>`

Answer (score 5):

## R, <strike>72 67</strike> 29 bytes

Edit: Thanks to @rturnbull for shaving off two bytes.

```
n=scan();`if`(n%%9|!n,n%%9,9)
```

Comment: I recently learned that `ifelse` can be replaced by `\`if\``, with identical behavior, which saves you a couple of bytes.

Comment: @rturnbull I was always wondering how ` `if` ` worked. Could you give an example or maybe add it to  [Tips for golfing in ?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97713/print-the-digital-root/97716#97716)

Comment: The simplest way to understand it is that it's a non-vectorized `ifelse`. In this case, `\`if\`(n%%9|!n,n%%9,9)` provides identical behavior to the code you've posted. As far as I can tell, this behavior is undocumented! I'll add a comment to the tips thread.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 7 bytes

```
{`.
*
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8L86QY9Li0vv/39DLhNTLmMTQy4zCwNDLlNLM0NjLhNLU0MDMwA)

I see lots of mathematical solutions, but in Retina the straightforward approach seems to be the best one.

#### Explanation

`` {` `` makes the whole program run in a loop until the string doesn't change anymore. The loop consists of two stages:

```
.
*
```

Convert each digit to unary.

```
.
```

Count the number of characters (=convert the unary number to decimal).

This works because converting each digit to unary with no separator between digits creates a single unary number which is equal to the sum of all digits.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```haskell
until(<10)$sum.map(read.pure).show
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/lm3Tma)

**Explanation:**

```haskell
until(<10)$sum.map(read.pure).show
                              show  -- convert int to string
               map(         ).      -- turn each char (digit) into
                        pure        --    a string 
                   read.            --    and then a number
           sum.                     -- sum up the list of numbers
until(<10)$                         -- repeat until the result is < 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 15 bytes

Includes +2 for `-lp`

Give input on STDIN

```
root.pl <<< 123
```

`root.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
$_&&=~-$_%9+1
```

This is the boring solution that has already been given in many languages, but at least this version supports `0` too

More interesting doing real repeated additions (though in another order) is in fact only 1 byte longer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%%$_+=chop%reg
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

#### Recursive method (4 bytes) (Credit to @ovs)

```perl
ωoΣd
```

```perl
      # implicit parameter ⁰ (refers to the last parameter)
   d  # list of digits in base 10
  Σd  # sum of list
 oΣd  # compose the two functions
ωoΣd  # repeat until the function returns the same result as the previous one
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/5zvxzi1P@//8fbahjYqpjbGKoY2ZhYKhjamlmaKxjYmlqaGAWCwA)

#### Modulus method (4 bytes)

```perl
→%9←
```

```perl
      # implicit parameter ⁰ (refers to the last parameter)
   ←  # previous number (n - 1)
 %9←  # modulus by 9
→%9←  # next number (n + 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@jtkmqlo/aJvz//z/aUMfEVMfYxFDHzMLAUMfU0szQWMfE0tTQwCwWAA)

Comment: [`ωoΣd`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/5zvxzi1P@//8fbahjYqpjbGKoY2ZhYKhjamlmaKxjYmlqaGAWCwA) works for the recursive version

Comment: cool ill change it soon

Answer (score 3):

### Java 7, 63 bytes

```
int f(int n){int s=0;for(;n>0;n/=10)s+=n%10;return s>9?f(s):s;}
```

Recursive function which just gets digits with mod/div. Nothing fancy.

### Cheap port

of [Jonathan Allan's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97730/14215) would be a measly 28 bytes:

```
int f(int n){return~-n%9+1;}
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 8 bytes

```
?(_9%)!@
```

using the equation `(n-1)%9+1`:

- `?` reads the input as decimal and pushes it to the stack
- `(` decrements the top of the stack
- `_` pushes a zero onto the top of the stack
- `9` push the top of the stack popped times 10 the digit (in this case, 9)
- `%` pops y, pops x, pushes x%y
- `)` increments the top of the stack
- `!` pops the top of the stack and out puts it as a decimal string
- `@` terminates the program

Answer (score 3):

### Hexagony, <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
.?<9{(/>!@!/)%'
```

More Readable:

```
  . ? < 
 9 { ( /
> ! @ ! / 
 ) % ' .
  . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BQU/BXsFGgUvBUqFaQUNBn8tOQVHBAYj1gWKaCqoK6gp6XCBVQPj/v4mlqaGBGQA)

-3 bytes by taking a different approach, making the 0 edge case trivial.

-1 byte by fixing 0 edge case bug

Using the formula ((n-1) mod 9) + 1 like a lot of other solutions aswell.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Æ=ìx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=xj3seA&input=NjgwMQ)

```
Æ=ìx     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ        :Map the range [0,U)
 =       :  Reassign to U
  ì      :  Convert to digit array
   x     :  Reduce by addition
         :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
[SODg#
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W1NPRGcj&input=NDk1MTA2)

**Explanation**

```
[        # infinite loop
 S       # split into digits
  O      # sum digits
   Dg#   # if length == 1: break
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes, thanks to Bassdrop Cumberwubwubwub*

Takes and returns a string.

```
f=s=>s[1]?f(''+eval([...s].join`+`)):s
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=s=>s[1]?f(''+eval([...s].join`+`)):s

console.log(f("1")); // -> 1
console.log(f("45")); // -> 9
console.log(f("341")); // -> 8
console.log(f("6801")); // -> 6
console.log(f("59613")); // -> 6
console.log(f("495106")); // -> 7
```

Comment: You can change `s.split\`\`` to `[...s]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
#0|@e+:0&
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=IzB8QGUrOjAm&input=NDk1MTA2&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
#0            Input = Output = a digit
  |           OR
   @e         Split the input into a list of digits
     +        Sum
      :0&     Call this predicate recursively
```

#### Alternative approach, 11 bytes

```
:I:{@e+}i#0
```

This one uses the meta-predicate `i - Iterate` to call `I` times the predicate `{@e+}` on the input. This will try values of `I` from `0` to infinity until one makes it so that the output of `i` is a single digit which makes `#0` true.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 12 bytes

```
->n{~-n%9+1}
```

Comment: `19` ? Shouldn't that be `9` ?

Comment: @TonHospel Yes, stupid error :P

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/), <s>19</s> 13 bytes

```
r{:~:+_s\9>}g
```

[Interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7B%3A%7E%3A%2B_s%5C9%3E%7Dg&input=12345)

Explanation:

```
r{:~:+_s\9>}g Code
r             Get token
 {:~:+_s\9>}  Block: :~:+_s\9>
   ~          Eval
  :           Map
     +        Add
    :         Map
      _       Duplicate
       s      Convert to string
        \     Swap
         9    9
          >   Greater than
            g Do while (pop)
```

Thanks to 8478 (Martin Ender) for -6 bytes.

---

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
ri(9%)
```

Suggested by 8478 (Martin Ender). [Interpreter](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=ri(9%25)&input=12345)

I was thinking about it, but Martin just got it before me. Explanation:

```
ri(9%) Code
r      Get token
 i     Convert to integer
  (    Decrement
   9   9
    %  Modulo
     ) Increment
```

Comment: Single-command map and reduce can both be written with prefix `:`, so you can do `:~:+`. It also doesn't hurt to run the block at least once so you can use a `g` loop instead of a `w` loop.

Comment: @MartinEnder `r{_,1>}{:~:+\`}w` works, but I don't know how on earth am I supposed to use `g` here.

Comment: E.g. like this: `r{:~:+_s\9>}g` (of course the closed form solution `ri(9%)` is much shorter.

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh gawd, for real now, I'm such a beginner...

Comment: The second one doesn't work on multiples of 9

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 24

*Smart*, *mathy* answer.

```
[ neg bitnot 9 mod 1 + ]
```

**63** for dumb iterative solution:

```
[ [ dup 9 > ] [ number>string >array [ 48 - ] map sum ] while ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>7</s> <s>4</s> <s>6</s> 7 bytes

Not the best one, but still beats a decent amount of answers:

```
|ejQ9 9
```

Like the previous version, but handling also cases of multiples of 9, using logical or.

---

**This version fails the 45 testcase**:

```
ejQ9
```

**Explanation:**

```
 jQ9  -> converting the input to base 9
e     -> taking the last digit
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26Qh%25tQ9&input=495106&debug=0)

[Try the previous version here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ejQ9&input=495106&debug=0)

---

**Previous solutions:**

```
&Qh%tQ9
```

**Explanation**:

```
    tQ    -> tail: Q-1
   %tQ9   -> Modulo: (Q-1)%9
  h%tQ9   -> head: (Q-1)%9+1
&Qh%tQ9   -> Logical 'and' - takes the first null value. If Q is 0 - returns zero, otherwise returns the (Q-1)%9+1 expression result
```

You're invited to [try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26Qh%25tQ9&input=495106&debug=0)!

Comment: Your 4-byte version fails test case **45**.

Comment: Won't this give 0 for multiples of 9?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it. Will do some fixing there. Apparently,  `jQ9` doesn't act like Jelly's `ḃ9` :-P

Answer (score 2):

## J, 8 bytes

```
**1+9|<:
```

Uses the formula `d(n) = ((n-1) mod 9) + 1` with the case `d(0) = 0`.

### Usage

```
   f =: **1+9|<:
   (,.f"0) 0 1 45 341 6801 59613 495106
     0 0
     1 1
    45 9
   341 8
  6801 6
 59613 6
495106 7
```

### Explanation

```
**1+9|<:  Input: integer n
      <:  Decrement n
    9|    Take it modulo 9
  1+      Add 1 to it
*         Sign(n) = 0 if n = 0, else 1
 *        Multiply and return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> 9 bytes bytes

```apl
××1+9|-∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0w9PN9S2rNF91DHDECikYMCVpmAIxCamQMLYBMQ0szAAUaaWZobGIBlLU0MDMwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <strike>54</strike> 51 bytes

```
i=input()
while~-len(i):i=`sum(map(int,i))`
print i
```

Thanks to Oliver and Karl Napf for helping me save 3 bytes

Comment: You can change `while len(i)>1` to `while~-len(i)` to save one byte.

Comment: I think you can omit the ticks around `input()` and force the input the be enclosed in quotes to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @KarlNapf I don't think you can do this when the input is an integer.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer, the op said that the input can be taken as a string

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>64</s> 29 bytes

C port from [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97730/53667)'s answer (with special case 0).

```c
f(i){return i>0?~-i%9+1:0;}
```

Previous 64 byte code:

```c
q(i){return i>9?i%10+q(i/10):i;}
f(i){i=q(i);return i>9?f(i):i;}
```

`q` takes the cross sum and `f` repeats taking the cross sum until a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 45 bytes

```
f=lambda x:x[1:]and f(`sum(map(int,x))`)or x
```

Takes the argument as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 15 bytes

```
.+
$*
1{9}\B

1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAouKwokKgoxezl9XEIKCjE&input=MQo0NQozNDEKNjgwMQ) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
.+
$*
```

Convert input to unary.

```
(1{9})*\B
```

Take 1-based modulo by removing nines that have at least one more character after them.

```
1
```

Count the remaining number of 1s to convert back to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 29 bytes

```perl6
{($_,*.comb.sum...10>*)[*-1]}
```

## Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
  ( # generate a sequence

    $_,         # starting with the input
    *.comb.sum  # Whatever lambda that splits into digits, and finds sum
    ...         # keep doing that
    10 > *      # until it is less than 10

  )[ * - 1 ] # get the last value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## braingolf, <s>20</s> 13 bytes

```
[Rdl1-M&+v>]R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1TzbcttGss/kV4wU2SDEi0nZziaUJR/ZcVKuWjuuuGpfaCYEQVCCBQIILrRdCs@ve7t77gAokVpnqzYPoTHT09PT95np0Udv7eV@FqZFP04WwVc/ifOCpVniB3nOzlgW/FmGWdBxRJPjnrY5zNLqXlKP6Poj95YB9DoHjoT@IwvWQZZT6//r1jyMgrjAxiPdeJkFweILNj7UjatkES5DQAHtE5qgp5D2JKKeHDxV4wTdr@P3RRbGlzja@fDB6THn0JkixZEHC33xy5tkkbObdouGZaVfJFnHxYZWcRXmg7UXlUj8BMa0Nu12y1ssOisAYOGSdQ4I5srLocllesAgLfMraDtlm3YrC/KgQJysihF7@WDozIKizGKWF14RDGgMkfbcRBvGflQuAhoxZksvygNEstHLeV94/nV1PWEcFqEX/QtxNKzN7GZ//aXXSqsAqLyHZGUFH4sLL76kQbKkPpednYHIcmKzw0FaUVCwYpUCcgQ5xSb8h2Rkq7VMMtZBqBDahqfw8wwHDECal8UVfHe7AhUN5AxFAP/Ky16Cxl4UndB1CRdwsbVhATCDNdJ2GJereZAdukzSgL9Ehxp0cJFl3pdBmNMvH4wSzZJP7FWWARNnL73YKRjIH5T2BgE2DisS5Ix/fcA491Yl6N48YJwbPeYhth6DxXIaemxeFuwyKdjRjUnnZoZWxHkrWG2JiHgAIvW9oqM7XLUEC9hQGDGE5pBCTVI@RY/5SRkLoaIoQOnKqFAyahIRjTClg/1r6CeMtrLmV@ES9X5sGQbMzqXGZ@OCXVMTylFYAe8kiltpEFz/VyiehFOL2IlBN9fLfifsjtzpXvS3W5fhOhDqKAnnk58Jawcfx72IdGyEjmavmSDnSeFdBx1aGiAZ7YeX4LijroJhM8EIPbQ6uYcFq5Dz1thzqhmAmJBLgr91GWKnYHZNI2mNwLm1l3ESYTJY4SKYl5fC7fXE5@t4Af5/zIbQkCdl5gdjVkLbMoyDBbSFKe8LPoeFHko2m49BbfBDgKy8MCb3yT@jJEnFJ4GBKS3AT4JbFQ3ImTGLg08iivSEq39D7XKqUAQgc3L@7ThIV@57abDQvd5i7cW4CnDe@J0CcPFr/Iro522bU86aJM05YzCwjRmY2tm58tAHXHxyelfEFxRRNcSciUhiyV0Q5gpXxrrg42Ea5XEsKFQGIA3lBiQ73yE1oUVOyLpsxM6lynFRCbUxaSPr9CJWATS9PmIiJV0Tbzqzt8HngiEEC3Pwq@bACUFPN6xDLnvjzlzNAa4FE/GRTgfSUA2YMO125bIOLSbfwcUa/2@YoPfwRXAZxjEylfP2EPIEG1ryExMEHaO2C@ZQy4V8nJxJYPOTVQqMDcaH3PWKbskFHqo4T1s1QtSqbuWaicu1oAUaxzFaTa4JxUGvRlz@P1t5UCHIK1xkHE2PfUSf11NuaISjP11BIsjV7CN4/QYtYw8fsppqfJwOVl7hX3UeTYb9H6ePXBEk1Izds6ZBtJSPpBnk9TmIMF2TZ1KJMMvCkVI7JH5J2zkbGuFJriz1wGe/BklJcM5ZRPCW0gnIV956b3l3NV15C0mGh7YULkTycYCJi0S1cWYqaAmjy7XVVWVM8Ub7Ve2nRdTJYCjXmMEyS1YvhbkOvDSNvnTiMop6TCYhLal9mSst6w/Lsmo@oJEaFacAVLNx5Iqhswm3@OmHeKaMQ3RRz2Q43cw0OcLsiZyzmjfdGgtJZsIPTZTvIYJBsyCunZ07E6cr4@THJIw7Ts9xu87UceXnh9hxN9OZq/PYW9AafCCctELXtKDTXf0U7zIijNFJmLoKU1bGv6ZB5uF24gS6WnoC6U6ct2HkLUKfpVEJ6QpmLmj6J0OVJQ8c905HcjLka6E5vNokszdJbEyySMp5hLMc3Xibwexu9B5YoWfMIHYJ59r4VE5JOXcWLEo/6HQ8yNwJDhHMLTc6eydWyncFXKiHAHbobgDN0Q3HuNFs2IFOPkaK1UVh9O8ljFUYm9Loj/aSRn@0mzTELHk5LzLPL6REGDoDFhZ5EC13k05/T@lQWttxm@TU301O/W8tp@P7yQnQhOAstahGw@F@poMDdhSXmiz/s/Sy/Qzo@D81oOPdBHP8rQXz6F6CWYTrcBFosTzdSyZPdxOInIR@lfXMv@xlO4@@le288YqrwRI2QBlhnbu7iOvRtxbX7/cSV/A5TWI6EjTt6D6mtLM16SkzL8zvK73j479FfMfHO8rv928tvwf384PJorTyh9H@otvRCcqZ6B/JfeX24G8R24MdpfbgW0vtfNfkcY8sXXN@rVYgCc0Kliwtim9LdgdlzI8VzXT92Tcj2Tq4vJXyIF7sRbc8x1NEDxqIpv0FXjDog7h7cPmnMo1C3ysMgpN4F0rN4w@isVfblk1QW6d3UHOitmYenb@rfSNeLsztJtf2Av/E26fiyovZCRhhsMoV6T0WXsYJpSqJ8CXSG@jTo43BhvefYPOpjNoDeR3dzDd3M4AvUfFgqHhw26Ah2c5oJ9gRwZ7sBHtCsI93gn1MsE92gn1CsE93gn1KsN/vBPs9wf5jJ9h/EOwPO8H@QLA/7gT7I8FGNd2Ngvguy9fH2FWvKw4YpMn3QJmgadOrutvbCIMBSq0WjcFxdGcuegmb9DxIPYAPk1hHyf1ipBEh6WymHrnucBH8cGOtwInBRB063PWgSPhpEMS5HLwRLEFQpc0Tm6WP2jBoS9jk6IbjwMMQDi6uE3gzTbrASdXJ2ELeATZtAeX1F4RSK8b9VNMNWugd2iHdMQhrVRbEf1ws/6QTUP/aNQJ8Dl4YrR3JI8pTnJHfF9DFQid1azpToUGuwJxT6VC@XYf4ids3kq0SGXhgtAAuMDxqp5Qlh@bO2lW7Rykzs1PIyJJC9l8in5Iw9P9nZopF/8TmZAVEHLN1RT9/CWKkCIIWBxJnqJhowTdkiUHxKQCPMhShZV1bP8I1rftfNe0DnXgvFNBUD5UA6BqKu@71Qoirn6k@g494DvSNbY3SPg4jtERQZy3eqkrCplIPTQDTzai7M30mbtwSiZkpB5IorZTlZRYQq3H13BQ9uZajG/q1Azedp2OzNIV1jae78wwmfS3YptB3FWeAhf0R8HCkkhoF/wwP7eujTTazPr@esMadN4JaqIanViYTFj55eenjgSsSuM4Y2SN549d4owptthxrqzss8c2VQ5@D4zRnarQUvWu7C@ciAqnCNJDBIYwMnHHST1LHMhVVxaHz7SC75BdkfLVyXhEoND5hc/v4cEvLKTz56v4qVfdg1mqf1ddaaej3twVdBaJvyoT2m0KrwJ5WrgIkTyVfvChiwkwrDHE0QxS2ZqYYhGneKEbWIhF61Q7slvnVXCdkB00q8JzJOhS8Jb8jKJ9u8TnKAyrEhv9BzyNKMLbzT5qQvBJZ7X6jY3SI7aCpIUY7OaBfl2qoVJ3dtmyjW/1Pk9vYw91YE8shDRu8N/9jbOn@B950V578tt/t2RbrJVTvmq418zuPH4ivZvCXh0eiR@eYRpRwXiar1OM1eGbwmIhaNZFRS2jITWpwgFaCWQdXHapie/VnCXhELRKAumjsGBmHTfulredRux1HEfvSvzNBBHpXwc8e1kfmlKK39thATOwahVuURPLln0mS8uMuSHM8LP8LN5rVoqIBS45eirv/4W5VDWbVANteq0A1B7xQcyJrNFtqOp60mTWUAnaqYLFRk0flCupTxD6j/kRsuHHNZ7KlRasfs7AnvoN4MeZVEaJlw9HYPMODtiXMIrmG8BuZaQvOq1ItnmLipwSYQw5yzf@9UVmGrtwgPZvuc364DLO82G7CVOhGZVqVIiVaDJVNBKJOiTCJpSB7BebqgRlvfnamKkQqGHlpj3XYa/BDlls2JBOEAGzVSKGExCpYJlWsOtiYcZiqXBBoQJI2Ofzcthcw55eyms6LOmHPYD8/ZgQzne5y5in3WhhYDizOPXxIjeciD1BOJdiXlN1PPCUxXp2Ueb0Jz0bZ3Cbu1Z7EETUUyC6MMHla737REEVlvFcg2yKpjWbYMPZC7gcknCzpU9Vdmp6LBl5KNA0hUA98sX3gi6aBisQLqbAHksgXlcpDo8hN1RB/5DXEwu9qLNCka9P1HJOPUwM/fDXg3hhKosrelPDH9cK3CRadauXTJaiDZRiBI0E/fc78Adk2iiB0dYUZnnjYR@16tyXTgJ/Js@Jwxxo5EKHY3n0oZWSfvJwXo7L8OuTH7ESDH3mlxGW6BcIZ8POQDVX3nrbbyzL2CZsZ3slFQmjHE0@8movxJ02iLx6/K9ixVo0XqEk2xXTyZtsg0kiJJM6EBnmwJfcVrkTl2MhUzMRxHKmaippE7b6oRi5fJaUmk@FUYeSLlrX7G5tfFb@gNEPxCFG8SyBVA67D72nbTDQQ3Ew0ds0z7kgzjMzhuYOxS3wE5scrR9VYCiJENK5lH385xsmDJpmSD/Upkg8j9@ALNisuzTRg0zjV2EHRGGw50/FWcNJEiEh4EoH1/bxkkw4YRQKh8hwcC1YtUdgKCPmz7LCL1nlqxNfRa8unBmMt5Q5krJgt1dwC5T/4Tc9J1PGasluiLVcJKODusg63eGJJjcBZj4ECc37RKAW7mTGsYXcJx4xOQYHi3ISKFzy9qdNBCZDhaCQpB0Ybn135F9hHHN1sIxVgHfJiSFOAextJHjGCDrNqfq3mn5rQ6p6x6cU2lkGqguoM7O1zkXn8WQJaFzivDJB9FpXONLNRH06PGAzPzANKVvXcvMKWaqjFwzbwe4sgywafsrCAPYuYBNgw@enFL9Nz5hjScRj858Da00Cd4RqvJ0CrDaKFQPHMLdt8iEEw5H3UWnX1rlxKNWNWhdbGwxJ6pucaCzWWkZSFWAavCTY5a249@b5MTOqZQX2@LZ43vQjy6o/MCCE@/yFk8I8aInrHZwRuk0ZzK9nRHhinPBF@d8l75Usl5W@PkaIzFmsyYvYAj9hC7hS1W4vt64uYPRLBviVwc9sPVSWwiG68JtqCoVtItT7qqCxIXGkZt05EID46kZHLvAYTDNWuCtdp9ou0DF/NtHxxy8Ef2gm5YaCO@C16K@Qx6hos57TNmMGtZ8wMRuS@UWjPkGHEpGty0g/YCXlz6CMGpTa1qtlqqsBc12GuCYaau12FPJQvEKwHYQ2Lr23DfD7rUGAMteAqj8gs0Xh08EPSEI88fivpMclgMDg0nO3he/4aymybfYjt5zFo3z30UaTmJuRr/iZUHKpTNjVmlfp2LgzLxZO3FfISHg5fXt2SPUgnPNWHQ6ZrqlyFvH6nqQjTDWQy@O3T@x7ffCU0dO23PjZOEhixEl8qdHwCNG9caNUQpO6svaeife0EQ7wrGGK2o763vXnS3DFeT7Vb7a1M0LOYFfv6VcttJQ36gYnhmcXDZHmyEXm3HWzwPbdxsW8dbuBQfuwPTHOObhCXfGHCYbCFtjraAuS24h3@4DURMWMR5t48Cvjx5EY8gOs4@EbC0O5XnwO/JIuQJyAHh26DqQj54nzVRzqC51vPe0yOq/dQmNxX35brZ9m@azJZP9Dy9cIRp37UXh8qWXqxoDpgCUlabiq0qhXzK4VqAvNY664@nBfHu4YMtr/Hwk0GMa@ndFk@IW4I@rcolz1C8N9l5vu66uZGzMvdOh1JJWk@8afCCqClkqgmKUW@mvgvskvIG@B/KiqTYsu9z2MRnsM4LfFRlAzQRuIAg7HmQeFo5XQbi4fil4O8nHMhd8CHnqjHYx4w1@mvnXFbn1GSPRvsNfckYkCuB2gSVaWLPd@JuD2rPwbTo6svwl7H/DWY5dPBWKuYpeGaJAKnPdyD8Dklu3iw8@TDNA2/4WIXkaDppuqZIQm3uU5AF0JQWFGCMm/4qnJSpBmJHSxPPPL7HV/5sWn3SD30M44TiA28WIk56ujA4xcBMk/BqwPPqkDyGu4xJ5rObte4eajlAM3T3z27Z8e6fSkw31dTVMJXcV8nvy2iUf/Nw@76fPrb19lpW/WJ0KWVBPIz@3Fln467tfWVuXcZcL0jTjcqIsrpoP0yybLAL/gQULCjG7k3AJasJ/h699kS9w/eKjhnkySlre4UpoTMJ2fzzAOKkmgJGr0IcI9WeLR3C2NjXCPaPqSUOMjEugXtIkQaoy/8RVNxhROtVrDp7UcwWftXPhyo769b6yCbJ/jXScgn5/gnI8RRDeNeADY8IByGZ2iAKMQrAdi/4cUAOL8ccOTfiSfqsOPBx8KwAVfxDtzPFftOXNIP2E/cMHPcHz/G6BIn9Hdc8D3JguxYLhujK92vguTRLkx2aKt8TBmFJVt9GGJK9VY8kPQ8Vls1i@8nU/43OfrLQ22izaQ8cZk9obyBiYK3IFN0jibmxzyFlDq7xBjkLX4G6PdfYr8jh/WYUxbL/g/8kFJHCYsGnrM/cV07cDevJBQrUVM3kLXfPNv4r6dQsc8O57dOw2OGCscCVb0a2/6rJ0kZLUipkJtCMw5m6m80mLmt8hSnbb5P4V8A@/Xrkx@fjobf/xs)
Links to the braingolf JS interpreter in TIO

#### Explanation

```
[Rdl1-M&+v>]R   Implicit input from command-line args to stack
[..........]R   Loop. Always runs once, will continue to run as long as the bottom value on the active stack is > 0
 R              Return to main stack, does nothing if already on main stack
  d             Pop top of stack, split into digits, push digits
   l            Push length of stack
    1-          Decrement top of stack
      M         Pop top of stack and push to next stack
       &+       Sum entire stack (all digits of input)
         v      Switch active stack to next stack
          >     Move top of stack to bottom
```

Decrementing the stack length, moving it to the second stack, and switching to the second stack before the end of the loop serves to use the decremented length as the loop counter. ie when the length is `1` (decremented to `0`) the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 57 bytes

```
while \$v>9 {set v [expr [join [split $v ""] +]]}
puts $v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxCsMgGAbQPaf4CNm6@BOVuOQixqEUoRabSDSmIJ7duj546eWb/z4DMgqBC8ycIBdGEErSDK4EMVlR2v123mKb8qpQok19aPsLJ/TncDt0DN4lTBnjaPAwpg7hSrFDq@0P)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 37 bytes

```
[[A~rdZ1<D]dsDx[+z1<S]dsSxdZ1<M]dsMxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2hkbGJqZm5hafA/OtqxriglytDGJTal2KUiWrvK0CYYyAyuAAn6Alm@FQX/DQ0CkhWAQDkvtTwnMy9VPzknNbGIKzolz9QiIAeoIjm2OAKsoCS1uEShvCixoCC1iMswJ6JCwcQURBqbgDlmFgZg2tTSzNAYLGtpamhgBmIhtCcnFqcW/wcA)

`[A~rdZ1<D]dsDx` decompose. Divide by 10 leaving quotient & remainder on stack until the value on the top of the stack is a single digit.

`[+z1<S]dsSx` sum. Add two topmost stack values until stack depth is one.

Macro `M` contains both of those, and `dZ1<M` to keep running itself until the final result is a single digit. `p` to print.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes

Input is taken as a string.

```javascript
f=n=>n>9?f(eval([...n].join`+`)+""):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PztI@TSO1LDFHI1pPTy8vVi8rPzMvQTtBU1tJSdMq739yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahpKhkqYmF5qYiSkWQWMTbErNLAywCZtamhkaYzPZ0tTQwAwo8R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 69 bytes

```forth
: f begin 0 swap begin 10 /mod >r + r> ?dup 0= until dup 10 < until ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBDoIwFET3nOKFraG2gTYiWs@iYpFEoakQj19bw@bPfzOTcXNYntXgssR4xHF7DOOE5PO9@g2UZP@ee2xgR7Bc@tUjz6zTMr7IkBqnDbu04v@mQQRECZWlTMuCe6ArFL5odDp1k19zkFl0a1Sdk1YrafDxBw)

#### Explanation

1. Place sum (starting at 0) on stack
2. Get remainder of number divided by 10
3. Add to sum
4. Replace number with itself divided by 10
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until number equals 0
6. Using sum as new starting number, repeat steps 1-5 until result is less than 10

#### Code Explanation

```forth
begin               \ start outer loop
  0 swap            \ place sum variable and move it down the stack
  begin             \ start inner loop
    10 /mod         \ get quotient and remainder of number/10
    >r +            \ temporarily "hide" quotient on return stack and add remainder to sum
    r> ?dup         \ retrieve quotient from return stack and duplicate if != 0
  0= until          \ end inner loop if sum is equal to 0
  dup 10 <          \ duplicate current "root" and check if less than 10
until               \ end outer loop if < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(+/.:'$)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0NbX89KXUVT38zU1Njs/38A)

**Explanation:**

Super straightforward. Break number into digits and sum up - do this until the result converges:

```
(+/.:'$)/ / the solution
(      )/ / do this until result converges
      $   / string, 1234 => "1234"
   .:'    / value each, "1234" => 1 2 3 4
 +/       / sum over, 1 2 3 4 => 10
```

Comment: In my implementation of k I made `x\y` encode `y` in base `x` with as many digits as necessary, so it's slightly shorter: [`(+/10\)/`](https://tio.run/##JcZBCoQgGAbQfadw0UKJyJ/U0u8oJTQbhygKokURdXVnpNV7U7l8lxiD44wXFcleVEzE3V15dz6bC@zAsE7gQ/iMMw6c2IS/s70jkP@jNGyyVoQ2xbSSYNK0NVS/VVaTNGh8/AE)

Comment: Nice. In the newer versions of kdb+ (I think from 3.4 and up) you can do `10\:`.. but not in oK - and `.:'$` is the same number of bytes - so I went with that :)

Comment: oK uses \ and requires a list on the left: `(,10)\`

Comment: Indeed, your implementation adds "as many digits as necessary", which is what you get from `\:` in kdb+ (3.4+), but for oK I'd need to know how many 10s to put in my list.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 69 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the console.

```vb
n=[A1]:While n>9:s=0:For i=1To Len(n):s=s+Mid(n,i,1):Next:n=s:Wend:?n
```

#### Test Function

```vb
For each x in Array(1,45,341,6801,59613,495106):[A1]=x:n=[A1]:While n>9:s=0:For i=1To Len(n):s=s+Mid(n,i,1):Next:n=s:Wend:?x"->"n:Next
 1 -> 1
 45 -> 9
 341 -> 8
 6801 -> 6
 59613 -> 6
 495106 -> 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic 1.1](http://www.qbasic.net/), 66 bytes

```
INPUT N
WHILE N>9
M=N
N=0
WHILE M
N=N+M MOD 10
M=M\10
WEND
WEND
?N
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 8 bytes

```
(+/10\)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcbBCkAwHAfgu6dwcCDJ/tlm2@9RWHGZRJQcSLz6WE7fNxXLsHjvTJqXxNqs9Lu5kuZ8NuPiA906Ie1cP844cGLL7B3tDYHsBxfQwYoTVIhUjCDDhJZU/eVaEJOorX8B)

this is based on [@streetster's oK answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97713/print-the-digital-root/167055#167055) but uses a feature specific to ngn/k: `10\x` is the list of digits of `x`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
ì‹9%›
```

Explanation:

```
ì‹9%›
ì     Takes input as integer
 ‹    Decrements
  9%  Modulus 9
    › Increment
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr///CaRw07LVUfNez6/98CAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), <s>105</s> 94 bytes

```
1 INPUT N
2 A$=STR$(N):N=0:FOR I=1 TO LEN(A$):N=N+VAL(MID$(A$,I,1)):NEXT:IF N>9 THEN 2
3 PRINT N
```

Output:

```
? 495106
 7

? 59613
 6

? 6801
 6
```

Explanation:

Convert input to a string, then walk the string, adding each digit to a total. If the resulting total has more than 1 digit, repeat the process.
Otherwise, print the total.

Okay, so it's not APL. But it will run on an 8-bit CP/M system. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), 6 bytes(SBCS on Keg wiki)

```
¿;9%1+
```

### Explanation:

```
¿#      Take implicit input
 ;9%1+# Digital Root Formula
# Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 11 bytes

```
1+9fPart((Ans-1)/9
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
⁽∑Ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%81%BD%E2%88%91%E1%BA%8A&inputs=15&header=&footer=)

```
⁽ Ẋ # Until the result converges...
 ∑  # Sum digits
```

Comment: Your first answer does not work when the input is a multiple of 9.

Comment: @Yousername Oops. Deleting.

Comment: https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJnIiwiIiwi4oG94oiR4oaUIiwiIiwiNDgyIl0=   another 3 byte solution

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
9⊤⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v/f8lHXkkddi/6nPWqbAGVzPeqbCuSlKZhYmhoamP0HAA)

Anonymous tacit prefix fork train.

```apl
 ⊤      ⍝ Tail of base conversion of                   
   ⊢    ⍝ right argument to
9       ⍝ base 9
```

Answer (score 1):

## [COBOL (GNU)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/), 131 bytes

```
PROGRAM-ID.A.DATA DIVISION.
	WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
	01 N PIC 9(9).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.ACCEPT N.COMPUTE N=FUNCTION REM(N- 1,9)+ 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxNC8IgGIDP7Ve8x41SJlTgoYOoDam9irqiY41tl9Gg6O9now6dn492uk0jGe6vlJy3lRc1MYoKqkQUoMzJBGORZouz9QeDFQnRelFpCFrGHykZIDgjgee8oNl8kVo1Xv9rIaV2EZBKW7smasDdvsFvD17XORJgK14sgSVlgjuKy@ymNd@wcvtu@/E6PBPpH133AQ)

## Explanation :

```
PROGRAM-ID.A.DATA DIVISION.
       * The first line is necessary and can't be removed
        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       * sadly so is this (accept input / output)
        01 N PIC 9(9).
       * This accepts input N that is upto 999,999,999 (output is via same)
        PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       * Time to start working on program itself.
        ACCEPT N.
       * Accepts the input from stdin.
        COMPUTE N = FUNCTION REM(N - 1, 9) + 1
       * compute n such that it is mod of n - 1 and 9 and then add one (standard forumla of --N%9+1
```

Output is via display N.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/), 9 bytes

```
⁺﹪⁻Ｎ¹¦⁹¦¹
```

**[TryItOnline!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R4673O1c9atz9fs@6QzsPLXvUCCQO7fz/38TS1NDADAA)**

#### Explanation:

```
⁻Ｎ¹  - take a integer input and subtract one from it
﹪     - modulo function
⁺     - addition function which given to it n-1%9 and 1  
⁹     - number 9 which is like 10-1
¦     - just a argument separator
```

PS: You could have reduced the argument separator by writing it in this order:
`⁺¹﹪⁻¹Ｎ⁹` but 7 is not a cool length to have, Also you could put a `Ｉ` before the whole thing to cast the result to printable integer value but since the numbers are represented as `-` characters in charcoal i ignored that.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΔSO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRg////TSxNDQ3MAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1OC/f/X6vyPNtAx1DG00DEx1TE2MdQxszAAco2MgVxTSzNDYx0TS1NDA7NYAA).

Or a minor alternative:

```
Δ1ö
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BTDw9v@/zexNDU0MAMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1MMD2/7X6vzP9pAx1DH0ELHxFTH2MRQx8zCAMg1MgZyTS3NDI11TCxNDQ3MYgE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ    # Loop until the result no longer changes,
     # using the (implicit) input-integer in the first iteration
 S   #  Convert it to a list of digits
  O  #  Sum those together
     # (after which the resulting digit is output implicitly)

Δ    # Loop until the result no longer changes,
     # using the (implicit) input-integer in the first iteration
 1ö  #  Convert it from base-10 to base-1
     #  (which is a non-vectorizing way to sum an integer's digits in 05AB1E)
     # (after which the resulting digit is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
‹9%›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigLk5JeKAuiIsIiIsIjQ5NTEwNiJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 75 bytes

```go
func f(n int)int{if n<10{return n}
k:=0
for;n>0;n/=10{k+=n%10}
return f(k)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6Fje900rzkhXSNPIUMvNKNIG4OjNNIc_G0KC6KLWktChPIa-WK9vK1oArLb_IOs_OwDpP3xYoma1tm6dqaFDLBVWVppGtWQs1sghsJMgODU2Faq6CIqCpOXkaaRqGmppIPBNTFK6xCaq0mYUBqoCppZmhMaoJlqaGBmZAIajNCxZAaAA)

## [Go](https://go.dev), Modulus solution, 29 bytes

```go
func(n int)int{return^-n%9+1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_B5oLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK6yxCKFNNulpSVpuhZ700rzkjXyFDLzSjSBuLootaS0KC9ON0_VUtuwFqLmZhFIEVivhqZCNVdBEVBlTp5GmoahpiYSz8QUhWtsgiptZmGAKmBqaWZojGqCpamhgRlQCGrzggUQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
}%9{
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJ9JTl7IiwiNDk1MTA2Il0=)

```
}%9{
   {  # decrement with implicit input
 %9   # mod 9
}     # increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 36 bytes

```
>0$:1(?v:&a%+&a,:1%-20.
^v?(a:~<
n<;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/385AxcpQw77MSi1RVVstUcfKUFXXyECPK67MXiPRqs6GK8/G@v///7plCoaWlgA) - [Interactive Version](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3E0%24%3A1%28%3Fv%3A%26a%25%2B%26a%2C%3A1%25-20.%5Cn%5Ev%3F%28a%3A%7E%3C%5Cnn%3C%3B%22%2C%22input%22%3A%22j%245%22%2C%22stack%22%3A%22495106%22%2C%22mode%22%3A%22numbers%22%7D)

Expects input as a number pushed onto the stack in advance.

### Explanation

There are 2 basic loops, one for summing the digits and one for checking if the number is less than 10 yet.

```
   :1(?v
```

Checks if the number is less than 1, if not all the digits are summed.

```
        :&a%+&a,:1%
```

Add the modulo to the accumulator, and then push the division again. We subtract the number %1 to make it a integer.

```
                   20.
```

Skip the first 3 letters of the bottom row.

```
^v?(a:~<
n<;
```

If the number is less than 10 (a is 10 in fish, it uses hexadecimal), print it and exit. Otherwise, go back to the start of the program with the number pushed to the stack.

```
>0$
```

Push the accumulator to the second from first spot on the stack.

Comment: You can save 20 bytes by performing the operations on the input and erroring out: `:a(?n:a%$a,:1%-+`

Answer (score 0):

## Perl <s>34</s> 28 bytes

Includes +1 for -p

```
s/./+$&/g,$_=eval while/../
```

Uses the method described in the question.

**Example:**

```
$ echo -n 495106 | perl -p DigitalRoot.pl
7
```

Comment: You need to count `-p` in your bytecount. (in that case, it will count for 3 bytes, but if you replaces the `''` with `""` then it's only 1 byte). And you can golf it further : the same approach can be written like `s/./+$&/g,$_=eval while/../`. Or you could do `s/(.)(.)/$1+$2/e&&redo` which is even shorter. And a shorter code (the approach is totally different) :  `$_=--$_%9+1`.

Comment: @Dada I was trying to figure out why it wouldn't run on the command line for so long that I must have forgotten to add the extra bytes when I gave up (I don't use perl much).

Comment: @Dada `s/(.)(.)/$1+$2/e&&redo` doesn't exactly follow the method given in the question either.

Comment: `perl -lpe 's%%s/\B/+/g;$_=eval%egr'`

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 57 Bytes

```
{n->for(;(n=(""+n).collect{(int)it-48}.sum())/10>1;){};n}
```

Repeatedly converts to string, sums the ascii conversion of the digits and continues while the resultant integer divided by 10 is greater than 1. Then it returns the mutated input.

Tried recursion too, cost more bytes though:

```
x={i->i?i%10+x(i.intdiv(10)):0};y={i->x(i)/10<1?x(i):y(x(i))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 79 Bytes

Golfed:

```
string R(string i){while(i.Length>1){i=i.Sum(o=>int.Parse(o+""))+"";}return i;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
string R(string i)
{
  while (i.Length > 1)
  {
    i = i.Sum(o => int.Parse(o + ""))+"";
  }

  return i;
}
```

Testing:

```
var printTheDigitalRoot = new PrintTheDigitalRoot();
Console.WriteLine(printTheDigitalRoot.S("1")); //1
Console.WriteLine(printTheDigitalRoot.S("45")); //9
Console.WriteLine(printTheDigitalRoot.S("341")); //8
Console.WriteLine(printTheDigitalRoot.S("6801")); //6
Console.WriteLine(printTheDigitalRoot.S("59613")); //6
Console.WriteLine(printTheDigitalRoot.S("495106")); //7
```

Comment: `string` is already `IEnumerable<char>` so you don't need to `ToCharArray()` before calling `Sum()` on it. `o-48` is a shorter than `int.Parse(o+"")`. Having said these, the mod 9 trick will be much shorter than actually summing the digits.

Answer (score 0):

## [Element](http://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 32 bytes

```
_2:1-+9/3:0<!{1-+2:0<!}1+-+9-*+`
```

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=XzI6MS0rOS8zOjA8IXsxLSsyOjA8IX0xKy0rOS0qK2A&input=NDk1MTA2)

This is using the typical closed-form formula, although it is noticeably more painful since Element lacks any rounding functionality.

```
_2:1-+9/3:0<!{1-+2:0<!}1+-+9-*+`
_2:                               make two copies of input
   1-+9/                          for one copy, subtract 1 and divide by 9
        3:0<!{1-+2:0<!}1+-+       floor it
                           9-*    multiply by -9
                              +`  add to the original input value, then output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 152 bytes

```
(let p((ol'())(n n))(let*-values(((q r)(quotient/remainder n 10))((l)(cons r ol)))
(if(= q 0)(begin(let((s(apply + l)))(if(< s 10)s(p'()s))))(p l q)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f n)
  (let loop ((ol '())
             (n n))
    (let*-values (((q r) (quotient/remainder n 10))
                 ((l) (cons r ol)))
      (if (= q 0)
          (begin
            (let ((s (apply + l)))
              (if (< s 10)
                  s
                  (loop '() s))))
          (loop l q))
      )))
```

Simpler version:

```
(define (f1 N)
  (define (getDigitList n)                   ; sub-fn  to get digits
    (let loop ((ol '())
               (n n))
      (let-values (((q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)))
        (if (= q 0) (cons r ol)
            (loop (cons r ol) q)))))

    (let loop2 ((n N))                       ; actual fn
      (define s (apply + (getDigitList n)))  ; get sum of digits
      (if (< s 10)
          s
          (loop2 s))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 1)
(f 45)
(f 341)
(f 6801)
(f 59613)
(f 495106)
```

Output:

```
1
9
8
6
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 2 bytes

```
9B
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UolS7IKlpSVpuhaLLJ2WFCclF0O5C5aZWJoaGphBeAA)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
9B  # Implicit input
 B  # Convert the input to a
9   # list of digits in base 9
    # Implicit output of last item
```