# Opposite of the digital root!

Tags: code-golf, math, number, kolmogorov-complexity, arithmetic

*<sup>Also known as the [analog root]</sup>*

([Opposite of the digital root!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123258/opposite-of-the-digital-root?answertab=active#comment302444_123258)) ;)

The digital root of a number is the continuous summation of its digits until it is a single digit, for example, the digital root of 89456 is calculated like this:

8 + 9 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 32

3 + 2 = 5

The digital root of 89456 is 5.

Given a digit as input via **STDIN**, print/return all of the possible two digit numbers that have that digital root. If you need it to, it can include itself, e.g. 05

These are all of the possible inputs and outputs:

**(You get to choose whether or not to include the leading zero for the digit itself)**

### I/O

**0** => 0 or 00 or nothing

**1** => 01 and/or 1, 10, 19, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64, 73, 82, 91 - **Make sure that 1 does not return 100**

**2** => 02 and/or 2, 11, 20, 29, 38, 47, 56, 65, 74, 83, 92

**3** => 03 and/or 3, 12, 21, 30, 39, 48, 57, 66, 75, 84, 93

**4** => 04 and/or 4, 13, 22, 31, 40, 49, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94

**5** => 05 and/or 5, 14, 23, 32, 41, 50 ,59, 68, 77, 86, 95

**6** => 06 and/or 6, 15, 24, 33, 42, 51, 60, 69, 78, 87, 96

**7** => 07 and/or 7, 16, 25, 34, 43, 52, 61, 70, 79, 88, 97

**8** => 08 and/or 8, 17, 26, 35, 44, 53, 62, 71, 80, 89, 98

**9** => 09 and/or 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 99

No [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), and it's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

> Congrats to [Heeby Jeeby Man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/heeby-jeeby-man) on [his amazing 46 byte brain-flak answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153072/69912)

Comment: does the number itself count as a two digit number? (05)?

Comment: [Inverse challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/97713/31625)

Comment: What should the output be for 0? And again, in a case like this where there are only 10 possible inputs, it would be of great benefit to supply the outputs in your challenge.

Comment: Your decision on how to handle zero invalidates many of the answers that were posted. It would be considerate to let the participants know you have made a decision.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I just updated the post

Comment: is the opposite of a digital root an analog root?

Comment: Why should `0` return `0`, that is not a 2 digits number (the same for all other 9 digits)

Comment: @edc65 You're right, I'm not sure exactly what I was thinking. I will modify the req.

Comment: Must `1` and `01` both be included (for input `1`)?

Comment: @user202729 no, you get to choose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
ITV
9+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=ITV%0A9%2B&input=2&warnings=0)

```
ITV\n9+ - if input: (don't print anything for 0 case)
 TV\n9+ -  repeat 10 times:
   \n   -    print ^
     9+ -   ^ += 9
```

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>27</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

Returns `0` for `0` or an array of solutions otherwise.

```js
n=>n&&[...1e9+''].map(_=>n+=9)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>n&&[...1e9+''].map(_=>n+=9)

for(n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  console.log(n, JSON.stringify(f(n)));
}
```

Comment: A downvote without any comment doesn't help much to improve the answer...

Comment: To some it might be unclear which part is the actual codegolfed function, and which part is a demonstration. It might be a good idea to just put the function itself straight below the *JavaScript* line.

Comment: @DavidMulder Thanks for the suggestion. That's actually the way I answer most of the time. Updated.

Comment: Nice solution! Sorry for dragging up an old solution but could you drop the `+` to save another byte? Though it would not work with stdin string that way I suppose.

Comment: @CraigAyre I'm not sure where this `+` came from... Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 9 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Adnan

```
тL<ʒSOSOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@xycfm1KRg/2D/wP//TQE)

### Explanation

```
тL<ʒSOSOQ   Main link. Argument n
тL<         List from 1 to 100, then decrement to get 0 to 99
   ʒ        Filter
    SOSO    Sum of all chars, twice
        Q   Compare to input
```

Comment: I think you can replace the infinite loop by `SOSO`, since the number will never be bigger than 99.

Comment: @Adnan Don't think, I assure you he can.

Comment: @Adnan Thanks, modified it.

Comment: `тL<` isn't really shorter than plain `99Ý`. ;)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well, I was probably trying to hard to save a byte there ;D

Comment: Main "link"? Since when 05AB1E has links? It's not Jelly.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
11Ḷ×9+ȧ@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Q8OGObYenW2qfWO7w//9/SwA)

Different algorithm than my other answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 46 bytes

```
{((()()()()()){}){(({}[()])<(({}{}[]))>)}}{}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDQ0MTBjWrazWBAtW10RqasZo2IBaQHaupaadZWwti//9vCgA)

### Explanation

This answer uses an idea from [Megatom's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153112/56656) namely using the stack height as the difference between the loop counter and the increment.   Like previous answers this answer has a large outer loop to catch all the zeros.  Inside the loop we push 10 to act as a counter, we then start another nested loop.  In this loop we decrement the counter by 1

```
({}[()])
```

Then we pop the top two items, which are the counter and the last item we calculated.  We add these to the stack height in order to counter balance the decrementation, we then push this twice, once for output and once so that it can be consumed to calculate the next result.  Pushing things twice means we accidentally push an additional value which needs to be removed at the end of execution.

The reason this just barely beats Megatom is Megatom's answer is forced to get its stack heights while the last result is still on the stack.  This means they are forced to use a rather expensive `[()]` to decrease the total by one.  By moving the duplicate to the end of the loop I am able to avoid having to use `[()]` at the cost of an additional `{}` at the very end of the program.  If Megatom were to use this strategy his answer would look like:

```
{<>((()()()()()){}){((({}[()])<>{}[]))<>}}<>{}
```

also 46 bytes.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 52 bytes

```
{((()()()()()){}){({}[()]<(({})((()()())){}{})>)}}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/WkNDQxMGNatrNas1qmujNTRjbTSADE2YLEgKyLXTrAVS//8b/TcEAA)

### Explanation

The main outerloop makes a special case for input of zero.  If zero is input we jump over the entire loop, pop zero and then output nothing.  Otherwise we enter the loop.  Here we push loop 10 times each time adding 9 to the top of the stack, keeping old values.  Since 9 preserves digital sums this will get us the next value.  Once the loop has expired we use the zero it generated to exit the loop which is then popped by the `{}` at the end.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 56 bytes

```
{([(((()()())){}{})]){({}()<(({})<(({}{}))>)>)}}{}({}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/WiNaAwg0QVBTs7q2ulYzVrNao7pWQ9NGA0hBSCCtaQeEtUAWhPv/v9F/QwA)

### Explanation

This version works very similarly to the last one, except we loop 9 times instead of 10 leaving out the original value.  In order to do this we have to rearrange the way we handle memory a bit.  All of the bytes we might have saved using this method get put into cleanup.

Comment: The 46 doesn’t preserve the original number :(

Comment: @JoKing Yeah, it just does the 2 digit cases.  Which I think is kind of the intention of the question, so that makes me pretty happy.

Comment: Nice Job! You earned the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

`f` takes an integer and returns a list of integers.

```hs
f d=[d,d+9..99^0^0^d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#DcJLCoAgFAXQrdxBg6J49C8HrSQKpKckpIUWLd/iHCuNm4y7lZfbnTzuME4FsvJKw36@pMkryRm9p@cQNXiaueBcEAmxlj9eYixRoUaDFh16DBghPg)

- Starts with the digit `d` and generates the range with every 9th number up to a bound of 99, *except* for the tricky case of `0`.
- To stop early for `0`, uses that the power `0^d==1` for `0` and `==0` for all other digits. Thus `99^0^0^d` gives `1` for `0` but `99` for anything else.

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, 15 bytes

```apl
{(×⍵)/+\⍵,10⍴9}
```

**How?**

`⍵,10⍴9` - concatenate input with 10 `9`s (`⍵ 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9`).

`+\` - cumulative sum.

`(×⍵)/` - expand signum times - where signum gives 1 for 1-9 and 0 for 0.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhGqNw9Mf9W7V1NeOAVI6hgaPerdY1v7//6h3VdqhFQY6j3o3WwIA)

#### Dyalog APL, 24 bytes

```apl
{⍵/⍨⎕=(⍵≠0)×1+9|⍵-1}⍳100
```

Requires `⎕IO←0`.

**How?**

```apl
                      ⍳100  ⍝ 0 .. 99
              1+9|⍵-1      ⍝ digit sum (⍵-1 mod 9 + 1)
        (⍵≠0)×             ⍝ edge case for 0
     ⎕=                    ⍝ equals to the input
 ⍵/⍨                       ⍝ compress with the range
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda n:n and range(n,100,9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WnkJiXolCUmJeeqpGnY2hgoGOp@b@gKDOvRCFNIzOvoLREQ1PzvyEA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
0g|g{t+₉}ᵃ¹⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@2@QXpNeXaL9qKmz9uHW5kM7HzVu@P/f@H8UAA)

#### Explanation

```
0g               Input = 0, Output = [0]
  |              Or
   g{   }ᵃ¹⁰     Accumulate 10 times, starting with [Input]
     t+₉         Take the last element, add 9
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <del>31</del> 27 bytes

```bash
seq $1 9 $(($1?99:0))|xargs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cWqigYqhgqaCioaFiaG9paWWgqVlTkViUXvz//38jAA)

previous

```bash
eval echo {$1..$(($1?99:0))..9}
```

Comment: how does one find the man pages / bash help / ?  about "{x..y..z}" ? what is it called?

Comment: found it: in man page, search [^.]\.\.[^.]  : `brace expansion: (...) A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is  an  integer.   (...) When the increment is supplied, it is used as the difference between each term.  The default increment is 1 or -1 as appropriate.`

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 48 bytes

```
{<>((()()()()()){}){(({}[()])<>[][()]({}))<>}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v9rGTkNDQxMGNatrNas1NKprozU0YzVt7KJjQQwgXxPIqa21sfv/3xAA)

I may add an explanation later.

Comment: Brilliant! I tried combining the +9 with the length to make a counter, but I never thought of doing it the other way around

Comment: [It's not over yet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153072/56656) :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 18 bytes

```
╗2╤DR⌠╜-9@%Y⌡░╜;)I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///R1OlGj6YucQl61LPg0dQ5upYOqpGPehY@mjYRyLPW9Pz/3wAA)

Explanation:

```
╗2╤DR⌠╜-9@%Y⌡░╜;)I
╗                   save input to register 0
 2╤DR               range(1, 100)
     ⌠╜-9@%Y⌡░      elements in range where function returns truthy:
      ╜-              subtract from input
        9@%           mod 9
           Y          is equal to 0
              ╜;)   push a copy of the input on the top and the bottom of the stack
                 I  if input is truthy, return the filtered range, else return the input (special-cases 0)
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
If[#==0,0,Range[#,99,9]]&
```

works for 0

Comment: Doesn't work for `0`. This also wouldn't include numbers whose digits add up to a number greater than 9. (e.g. `9` wouldn't have `99` in the output).

Comment: I see what you mean. Do you inspect only "my" codes? cause many codes here don't work for 0...

Comment: Welp, I tend to focus on Mathematica code because that's the language I know best. Didn't mean to target you or anything. I apologize if it seemed like it.

Comment: all fixed and working

Comment: What? No builtin?

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 41 Bytes

prints underscore separated values

```php
for(;100>$a=&$argn;$a+=$a?9:ERA)echo$a._;
```

`ERA` is the shortest constant in PHP with the value `131116`. You can replace it with the boring alternative `100` or end the program with `die`

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0d7142b549fbc396e867eba18a644213aa17928)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
⁵²Ḷµ,³%9EµÐf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4oG1wrLhuLbCtSzCsyU5RcK1w5Bm////MQ)

**How It Works**

```
⁵²Ḷµ,³%9EµÐf
⁵             - literal 10
 ²            - square
  R           - lowered range: 0 to 99 inclusive.
   µ     µÐf  - filter based on:
    ,³          - element and input
      %9        - mod 9
        E       - are equal
```

Comment: When I use 1 as an argument it also gives out 100, which is not two digit

Comment: This doesn't split the 0 and 9 cases.

Comment: This *still* [doesn't work for `0`](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4oG1wrLhuLbCtSzCsyU5RcK1w5Bm////MA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
{<>((((()()())){}{})()){({}<(({})<>({}))><>[()])}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/2sZOAwQ0QVBTs7q2uhbEqNaorrXRABKaQHkgqWlnYxetoRmrWVtrY/f//38TAA)

My first foray with Brain-Flak, and I think I've done pretty well. Anyone with more experience have advice?

#### How It Works:

```
{ Don't do anything if input is 0
  <>((((()()())){}{})()) Switch to other stack and add 9 and 10
                         10 is the counter, 9 is to add to the current num
  { While counter
     (
       {} Pop the counter
       <(({})<>({}))> Get a copy of the 9, switch to the other stack and add it to a copy of the top of it. Use <...> to make it return 0
       <>[()] Switch to the other stack and decrement the counter
     ) 
  }
}<> Switch to the stack with the values on it
```

Comment: Good job! Welcome to Brain-Flak.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>48</s> 51 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @WheatWizard*

```
lambda n:[x for x in range(100)if~-n==~-x%9or x==n]
```

Comment: try `~-x` instead of `(x-1)`

Comment: still with @WheatWizard's tip, remove the space in `if ~-x%9`

Comment: Now you can do `~-n==~-x%9or x==n` to save a byte

Comment: [This gives a 0 for 9](https://tio.run/#python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WnkJiXolCUmJeeqpGnY2hgoGOp@b@gKDOvRCFNIzOvoLREQ1PzvyEA)

Comment: I need to ask a silly question... I'd like to run this. How do I get this code to run? There are some constructs here I'm learning about (mainly the ~ operator)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ȷ2ḶDS$ÐL⁼¥Ðf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//yLcy4bi2RFMkw5BM4oG8wqXDkGb///85)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 35

```
print_r(range($argn,!!$argn*99,9));
```

Creates the range `[$argn, 100)` with a step of `9` as array and prints it. If the input is `0` it creates the range `[0,0]` => `array(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
pryr::f(x+0:(10*!!x)*9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0KzQtvASsPQQEtRsUJTy/J/moaBJleahiGIMAIRxiDCBESYgggzEGEOIixAhKXmfwA)

The TIO link uses `function(x)` instead of `pryr::f`, since TIO doesn't have the `pryr` package installed.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 6 bytes (old version)

[Working commit](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/tree/d8ecd04b7b643e54f5d31de3fb962213a1f3f2b1)

```
TXU#sq
```

Explanation:

```
TX     -   10**2
  U    -  range(^)
   #   - filter(^)
    s  -   digital_root(^)
     q -  ^==input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->a{[*a.step(99,9)]*a|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlorUa@4JLVAw9JSx1IzViuxJjq29r@GgZ6epaZebmJBdU1FDVeBQnSFjkJadEVsLFftf0MA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
Ｉ∧Ｎ⁺Ｉθ×⁹…¹¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzEvRcMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTRyEgp7QYIlkI5IVk5qYWa1jqKAQl5qWnahgaakKA9f//hv91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved <s>2 bytes by not printing anything for zero input and 1 byte by using vectorising operations</s> 3 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only. Explanation:

```
         ¹¹ Literal 11
        …   Range
       ⁹    Literal 9
      ×     Vector multiply
     θ      (First) input
    Ｉ       Cast to number
   ⁺        Vector add
  Ｎ         Input digit as a number
 ∧          Logical AND
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8zTcM5sbhEo1BTM6AoM68EwgvIKS3W8MwrKC3xK81NSi3S0NRRCMnMTS3WsNQJSsxLT9UwNNQEgv//Df/rluUAAA)?

Comment: i think i just found an alternative that prints 0, [here](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzEvRcMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTRyEgp7QYIlkI5IVk5qYWa1jqKAQl5qWnahgaaoKB9f//hv91y3IA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

`f()` need not actually be called with any argument; the `n` is just there instead of outside the function to save a byte.

```c
f(n){for(scanf("%d",&n);n&&n<100;n+=9)printf("%d ",n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SKM4OTEvTUNJNUVJRy1P0zpPTS3PxtDAwDpP29ZSs6AoM68ELKugpAOUrf0P5CvkJmbmaWhyVXNxpmloWnPV/jcHAA)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by putting the `printf` inside the loop header: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SKM4OTEvTUNJNUVJRy1P0zpPTS3PxtLQuqAoM68ELK6gpJOnbWupqWld@x8oppCbmJmnoclVzcWZpqFpzVX73xAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @DLosc myeah, but then it starts one number too late.

Comment: The wording could be clearer, but the question does allow starting at (e.g.) 10 instead of 1: "... all of the possible two digit numbers that have that digital root. *If you need it to*, it *can* include [the single-digit number] itself, e.g. 05." In other words, including the single-digit number in the output is *permitted* but not *required*.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11 bytes

```
?56+ř⁻9*+:;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f3tRM@@jMR427LbW0raz//7cAAA)

```
?               implicit input; if input is truthy:
 56+            push 11
    ř⁻          řangify; decrement
      9*        multiply by 9
        +       add input
         :;     otherwise, do nothing; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `H`, 6 bytes

```
ʁ'∑∑?=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIIiwiIiwiyoEn4oiR4oiRPz0iLCIiLCIxIl0=)

Port of kalsowerus's 05AB1E answer.

A port of Kip the Malamute's Pyt answer would be **8 bytes**:

```
:[11ʁ9*+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI6WzExyoE5KisiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

##### Explanation

```
ʁ'∑∑?=  # H flag pushes 100
ʁ'      # Filter range(100) by:
  ∑∑    #  Digit sum twice
    ?=  #  Equals the input
```

```
:[11ʁ9*+  # Implicit input
:         # Duplicate
 [        # If input is not 0:
  11ʁ     #  Push range(11)
     9*   #  Multiply by 9
       +  #  Add to input
          # (Otherwise, do nothing)
```

Comment: "Make sure that 1 does not return 100"

Comment: @DominicvanEssen fixed. That was just Vyxal implicitly converting 100 to a 1-based range instead of a 0-based range.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

I use a ternary to catch the `0` case, and a range `n:9:99` to create the numbers. In julia a range is an `AbstractVector` and can be used in place of an actual `Vector` of numbers in most cases, but it will just print as `1:9:91` which doesn't satisfy the challenge, so I wrap it in `[_;]` to collect the contents into a `Vector`.

```julia
n->n>0?[n:9:99;]:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@mYKuQlJqemfc/T9cuz87APjrPytLK0tI61srgf2peCldafpFCJlCRgZUlF6dDcUZ@uUKmTppGpiYXUPY/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 25 + 1 (`-n`) = 26 bytes

```perl
say;!$_||($_+=9)>99||redo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sdJaUSW@pkZDJV7b1lLTztKypqYoNSX//3@jf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5gEA)

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, 33 bytes**

```
(fn[n](if(> n 0)(range n 100 9)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 38 bytes

```clj
(defn f[n](if(pos? n)(range n 100 9)))
```

or as anonymous function which is 29 bytes

```clj
(#(if(pos? %)(range % 100 9))n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlNS1PIS06L1ZBIzNNoyC/2F4hT1OjKDEvPVUhT8HSUsFSU1Pzv0ZBUZ5GmoIpkAkA)

thanks @steadybox

Comment: The output when `n=9` is missing the last number, `99`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlNS1PIS06L1YjM02jIL/YXiFPU6MoMS89VSFPwdJSwVJTU/O/RkFRnkYaiP0fAA) Also, you can save a byte by removing the space between `f[n]` and `(if(...`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
?11R9*+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FsvtDQ2DLLW0ITyo4IKFphAGAA)

Port of Kip the Malamute's Pyt answer.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `H`, \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
gdSdSA$=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSh1LsgqWlJWm6FivSU4JTgh1VbCFcqOiChaYQBgA)

Port of kalsowerus's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanations

```python
?11R9*+  # D flag duplicates input
?        # If input is not 0:
 11R     #  Push range(11)
    9*   #  Multiply by 9
      +  #  Add to input
         # (Otherwise, do nothing)
```

```python
gdSdSA$=  # H flag pushes 100
g         # Filter range(100) by:
 dSdS     #  Digit sum twice
     A$=  #  Equals the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 62 bytes

```
sub x{$f=$_[0];@x=("0$f",$f);push@x,map$f+$_*10,(1..9)if$f;@x}
```

There's bound to be a shorter way

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 12 bytes

```
I:ZhbF:N9+|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MqKiPJzcrPUrvG@v9/QwA)

#### How it works

```
I:ZhbF:N9+|;

I             Take input as number
 :            Duplicate
  Z           Pop and skip one if nonzero
   h          If zero, print the top as number and halt
              Otherwise...
    bF....|   Repeat these commands 11 times
      :N      Print top as number, with newline
        9+    Add 9
           ;  Halt
```