# Iterate through addition of number sequence until a single digit

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Challenge: With any given number that has multiple digits, every digit in the number needs to repeatedly be summed together until the sum is a single digit number. To make things interesting, if there's a 0 in the number, then it must equal 26, because zero starts with the letter z, which is the 26th and final letter of the alphabet.

Example:

With an input of \$120\$:

- \$1 + 2 + 26 = 29\$
- \$2 + 9 = 11\$
- \$1 + 1 = 2\$

The answer would be 2.

Output:

```
120
29
11
2
```

Scoring:

The code that's written in the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97713/print-the-digital-root)

Comment: I'm not sure if this provides enough of a difference to code-golf to prevent this from being considered a duplicate.

Comment: If there is a zero in the number should the entire sum be treated as 26 or just the digit?  To me it seems like the entire sum, but [the go answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254128/56656) just treats the digit as 26.

Comment: Only the digit.

Comment: @GrainGhost I would argue it does mainly because it cannot be solved simply by taking the input mod 9.

Comment: @GrainGhost If my memory serves me correct, questions that improve on the quality of other questions have been accepted. This one is a lot clearer on the requirements, and there's lots of things that were allowed in 2016 that aren't allowed now, in 2022 (almost 2023). Also, this question has the added requirement that "0" be treated as "26". This question does need extra test cases, and the usual "standard loopholes blah blah blah".

Comment: @Larsenv Is the input required to be a number? Or can it be a string or an array of digits as well? Also, can you add an extra test case, where the sum has a 0, like `5555`?

Comment: This program doesn't require the use of a string.

Comment: It's currently a little unclear whether we may only output the final digit or if we need to output the series of numbers since the post says both "The answer would be 2." and "Output:...". Could you clarify which it is or whether both are acceptable? (I had assumed the "output" was the required one personally.)

Comment: @Larsenv Uh ... I never asked if a string is required... But anyway, which input formats are allowed?

Comment: I guess either are acceptable this point. I was intending on saying to print the full output, but the most important part is the single digit number you make at the end.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Do26SƲƬ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer and yields a list of non-negative integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l38gs@NimY2v@//9vaGQAAA)**

#### How?

```
Do26SƲƬ - Link: integer, n
      Ƭ - collect up (starting with X=n) while distinct applying:
     Ʋ  -   last four links as a monad:
D       -     decimal digits (X)
  26    -     26
 o      -     logical OR (vectorises)
    S   -     sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 97 bytes

```go
func f(n int){println(n)
if n<10{return}
k:=0
for;n>0;n/=10{if n%10<1{k+=26}else{k+=n%10}}
f(k)
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjcT00rzkhXSNPIUMvNKNKsLioBUTp5GniZXZppCno2hQXVRaklpUV4tV7aVrQFXWn6RdZ6dgXWevi1QCqRE1dDAxrA6W9vWyKw2Nac4FcQECdbWcqVpZGty1UIs2ga2B2SxhqZCNVDK0MgALrlgAYQGAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes (17 nibbles)

```
/`.$+.`@~$?$$26@
```

Returns just the final digit.  If we can return the sequence (for instance, 120 29 11 2, as in the example) then we can drop the initial `/` and final `@` for 7.5 bytes (`` /`.$+.`@~$?$$26@ ``)

```
 `.               # iterate while unique:
      `@ $        #  convert to digits in base
        ~         #  10 (default)
     .            #  now map over each digit
          ?$      #   if it's nonzero
            $     #   then that digit
             26   #   otherwise 26
    +             #  now sum the list
/                 # finally, fold from right
               @  #  each time returning right argument
                  #  (so returning the last element)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_ì xª26}hN â
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=X%2bwgeKoyNn1oTiDi&input=MTIw)

```
_ì xª26}hN â     :Implicit input of integer U
_                :Function taking an integer as argument
 ì               :  To digit array
   x             :  Sum of each
    ª26          :    Logical ORed with 26
       }         :End function
         N       :Starting with the array of all inputs (i.e., [U])
        h        :Run the function and push the result to N until length U
           â     :Deduplicate
                 :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 14 bytes

```
{`0
998
.
$*
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OsGAy9LSgkuPS0WLS@//f0MjAwA) Only outputs the final digit. Explanation:

```
{`
```

Repeat until the value doesn't change, i.e. it's a single digit `1-9`.

```
0
998
```

Replace `0`s with `998`, which has a digit sum of 26.

```
.
$*
.
```

Calculate the sum of the values of the digits by converting each digit separately to unary and then converting the total back to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel (ms365), 83 bytes

[image]

Formula in `B1` for 117 bytes:

```
=TOCOL(SCAN(A1,ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=1,a,LET(c,--MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1),d,SUM(IF(c,c,26)),IF(a=d,NA(),d))))),3)
```

Formula in `C1` for 83 bytes:

```
=REDUCE(A1,ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,--MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1),SUM(IF(c,c,26)))))
```

---

**Note:** If Excel's 15 digits precision becomes a problem with huge numbers than `A1` should be text input. I have tried but never needed more than 9 iterations to get to a single digit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>68</s> <s>66</s> 60 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)

```python
f=lambda n:n>9and[n]+f(sum(int(d)or 26for d in str(n)))or[n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3bdJscxJzk1ISFfKs8uwsE_NSovNitdM0iktzNTLzSjRSNPOLFIzM0oBkikJmnkJxSZFGnqYmUBSoDmLG2oIikMo0DUMjA01NiBjMfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
ω(ṁ|26d
```

*Edit: -2 bytes by copying the logical-OR trick from [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254150/95126)*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3ynxsOdjTVGZin///83NDIAAA)

Returns just the final digit. If we need to return the sequence (for instance, 120 29 11 2, as in the example) then exchange the initial `ω` for `U¡` for [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/TQQo2HOxtrjMxS/v//b2hkAAA) (`U¡(ṁ|26d`).

```
 ω(             # Find fixed point by iterating:
          d     #  get decimal digits
   ṁ            #  map over each digit
                #  and sum the result:      
     |          #   second arg if truthy (1-9)
       26       #    otherwise 26
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:[n][n-9:]or[n]+f(sum(int(c)or 26for c in`n`))
```

A recursive function that accepts a non-negative integer and returns a list of non-negative integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwFAX3nuIt/6cKNgvBgCcJgcZqNNC@lDQuPH2Mm2FmMdu3vjNNa/G2hPX@CKB19I6nq/W5dB2i7J9VEqvMmgvMJXbOSJw4qbZ/sReWtFcpga@nmFEVA9xozt4esJV@g0dEobYf)**

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:[n][n-9:]or[n]+f(sum(int(c)or 26for c in str(n)))
```

A recursive function that accepts a non-negative integer and returns a list of non-negative integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsIwEEX3nmKWM1TBRhAMeJKQRdoaDbQ/ZRIXnj42m8fnwX/7r34ybq3F5xq2aQkE6@AdLg/rsx5ziFy@GydUniUrmXs8OFMClaoMEWndoJs1lcoa8H6xGUVoIDeaq7cn2rUXcKbYL@0P)**

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer - you need to include the ```f=``` for a recursive function, since an anonymous function won't know it's own name to call itself...

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 53 bytes

```factor
[ [ >dec "0" "J" replace 48 v-n Σ ] to-fixed-point ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BasMwEETv@Yqpz7Xslh4aBwK5JLiUXEJPIRhFXtsisiSkTZp@T/@nv@TW9qW3HWaYN9tIxS4MH4dyvysQvdHM2rboJXfiRqMZZ@FliBTm@2q1cjVBuf6srZxCPhDzlw/aMi4ULBmsUO4LtM40i817uTkUWNekYK/9mcI6chhJeADddeQIbbGd5iAXy@UKkQgds49FltVORdFM7kgWLrSZcpbJcvbpQp1WVctV9Vf/@G@t6Lg3i6fnfDjiOMOTPEHyliCQN1IRXl5xSy1@vnECu7TRd6pT78YvToOSxkAMvw)

The only mildly clever thing this does is replace `0` with `J` in the string representation of the number so it ends up as 26 after converting to digits.

- `[ ... ] to-fixed-point` Call `[ ... ]` on the input until it stops changing.
- `>dec` Convert a number to a string.
- `"0" "J" replace` Replace the zeros with `J`.
- `48 v-n` Subtract 48 from each code point in the string.
- `Σ` Take the sum.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
Wg
QT=Qsm|sd26`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzydKzDENrA4t6Y4xcgs4f9/QyMDAA)

#### Explanation

```
                  implicit Q = eval(input())
WgQT              while Q >= 10 (print Q when this is checked)
    =Q            assign Q to
      s           the sum of
       m     `    map the digits of Q to
        |sd26     themselves, unless they are 0, then 26
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
F=->n{(p n)>9?F[n.digits.sum{_1<1?26:_1}]:n}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN3XcbHXt8qo1ChTyNO0s7d2i8_RSMtMzS4r1iktzq-MNbQztjcys4g1rY63yaiF6lrlFGxoZxEI4MIMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
<A?N:ßNpUì xª26)Ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=PEE/TjrfTnBV7CB4qjI2Kcw&input=MTIw)

Explanation:

```
<A?N:ßNpUì xª26)Ì
                  # At first iteration, U = input, N = [input]
<A                # Check whether U is less than 10
  ?               # If so:
   N              #  Output N
    :             # Otherwise:
        Uì        #  Get the digits of U
           x      #  Sum them with this modification:
            ª     #   Replace 0
             26   #   With 26
      Np       )  #  Append the result to N
     ß            #  Repeat the program with new U:
                Ì #   The last number in N
```

[Alternate](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=qEGp305wVewgeKoyNinMCk4&input=MTIw) which avoids the ternary expression, but it's not shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

Returns a comma-separated string.

```javascript
f=n=>n>9?n+[,f((g=n=>n&&(n%10||26)+g(n/10|0))(n))]:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PztI@TztaJ01DIx3MV1PTyFM1NKipMTLT1E7XyNMHsg00NTXyNDVjrfL@J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrpGkYGgGluFDFTIFAU/M/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = n =>             // f is a recursive function taking the input n
n > 9 ?              // if n has more than one digit:
  n + [,             //   append n, followed by a comma,
    f(               //   followed by the result of a recursive call:
      ( g = n =>     //     g is a helper recursive function taking n:
        n && (       //       stop if n = 0
          n % 10     //       otherwise, extract the least significant digit
          || 26      //       replace it with 26 if it's 0
        ) +          //
        g(           //       add the result of a recursive call with ...
          n / 10 | 0 //         ... floor(n / 10)
        )            //       end of recursive call to g
      )(n)           //     initial call to g
    )                //   end of recursive call to f
  ]                  //
:                    // else:
  n                  //   append the final n and stop the recursion
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
f0₄V∑)↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJmMOKChFbiiJEp4oaUIiwiIiwiMTIwIl0=)

Outputs the whole list. I may have forgotten there's a built in for 26 lol.

### Explained

```
f026V∑)↔
      )↔ # Until applying the following doesn't result in a different value, collect intermittent values. 
f         #   flatten the function argument
 026V     #   and replace 0s with 26 (the 0 and 26 are pushed separately)
     ∑    #   sum the resulting list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 79 bytes

```
:a
/^a{10}*(A|$)/s/$/ABBBBB/
s/B/AAAAA/
s/(a+)\1{9}(.*)/\1\U\2/
ta
s/A+/\L&/
ta
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlWbSSrqtS7IKlpSVpuhY3_a0SufTjEqsNDWq1NBxrVDT1i_VV9B2dQECfq1jfSd8RBEBMjURtzRjDastaDT0tTf0Yw5jQGCN9rpJEoJSjtn6MjxqIAzEWavqCmxWJAwQgDgAA)

**Explanation:**

```
:a
# check for divisibility by 10
# if it is divisible, then add 26 to sum
# B = 5A, A = 1, ABBBBB = 26
/^a{10}*(A|$)/s/$/ABBBBB/
s/B/AAAAA/
# divide the number by 10 and add remainder to the sum
s/(a+)\1{9}(.*)/\1\U\2/
ta
# change the sum back to normal number
s/A+/\L&/
# repeat till the number is single digit
# uses the fact that division is performed only on numbers > 9
# and otherwise the sum is zero, thus no conversion back to normal number is performed
ta
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｗ⊖Ｌθ≔ＩΣＥθ∨Ｉκ²⁶θθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDJTW5KDU3Na8kNUXDJzUvvSRDo1BTU1PBsbg4Mz1PwzmxuEQjuDRXwzexQKNQR8G/CCKUramjYGQGVAikCzWtuQKKMvNKgDqt//83NDL4r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Only outputs the final digit. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⊖Ｌθ
```

Repeat until the input only has one digit.

```
≔ＩΣＥθ∨Ｉκ²⁶θ
```

Cast each digit to integer, replace zeros with 26, take the sum, then cast back to string again.

```
θ
```

Output the final digit.

Comment: This answer doesn't work with the newer version of Charcoal on ATO because I've since introduced a regression. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 11 bytes

```
⟨$⟨26∨⟩¦Σ⟩ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9H8FSpAbGT2qGPFo/krDy07txhErfr/39DIAAA)

Outputs the final result because that seems to be allowed. Uses a similar algorithm to the Jelly answer.

### Explained

```
⟨$⟨26∨⟩¦Σ⟩ª
⟨       ⟩ª  # Until the result doesn't change:
 $⟨26∨⟩¦    #   logical or each digit of the argument with 26
       Σ   #   digital sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
k;f(n){for(k=0;n;n/=10)k+=n%10?:26;n=k>9?f(k):k;}
```

The expression `n%10?:26` returns `n % 10` if it's not 0, otherwise 26, where `:?` is the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator), a GNU extension to the language.

This returns the last number in the sequence. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY6xDsIgFADn8hUvmhqIVqmDiWLpZ7i4NCD6An00tupg@utidb274UxxNSYlrxwn8Xbxzn0lFSnaVKUUfllRXsr6sN0pqrze1457cfBqTHMkEx72Asd@sBjXN80Y0sDaBok/I1rB3iybCJBi2euG4QK8Nw05PsvtbAULEqBBCpZl3X3q/hwKDbk90@RpBb8nodiYyq38GBeaa5@KE8UC2y6gweEL)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΔS0₂:O
```

Only outputs the final digit.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRgg0dNTVb@//8bGhkAAA)

Outputting each intermediate step including the first would be 1 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) longer:

```
Δ=S0₂:O
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BTbYINHTU1W/v//GxoZAAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ        # Loop until the result no longer changes, using the (implicit) input:
  S      #  Convert it to a list of digits
   0₂:   #  Replace all 0s with 26s
      O  #  Sum the list together
         # (after which the resulting digit is output implicitly)

 =       #  Print the current integer with trailing newline (without popping)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 161 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate_input][N
S S N
_Create_Label_OUTER_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T N
S T _Print_as_integer][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10_(\n)][S N
S _Duplicate_10_(\n)][T N
S S _Print_as_character][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   S T N
_If_negative_jump_to_Label_EXIT][S S S N
_Push_digitSum=0][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S T T   _Modulo][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S T N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_ZERO][N
S S S S N
_Create_Label_RETURN][S T   S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(digitSum)][T S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10][T S T S _Integer-divide][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_OUTER_LOOP][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_ZERO][S N
N
_Discard_top][S S S T   T   S T S N
_Push_26][N
S N
S S N
_Jump_to_Label_RETURN]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Outputs each intermediate step (since that's shorter than only outputting the final digit anyway).

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##TY1BCoAwDATPm1fsE9QfiRT0Jij4/DSbVDGFZDtM02c/7nad69bcSVocGFSZ1YpRIArEsJRTziz4zs@LlraUpJZvBHTBz6sF9Ztc1NCCQWnu8zJ1) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = STDIN as integer
Start OUTER_LOOP:
  Print n as integer to STDOUT
  Print '\n'
  If n is smaller than 10 (n-10 is negative):
    Stop the program with an error by jumping to nonexistent Label EXIT
  Integer digitSum = 0
  Start INNER_LOOP:
    Integer d = n modulo-10
    If d == 0:
      d = 26
    digitSum = d + digitSum
    n = n integer-divided by 10
    If n == 0:
      n = digitSum
      Go to next iteration of OUTER_LOOP
    Go to next iteration of INNER_LOOP
```